# Java Swing - How to handle generics in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, generics, java-7

I have:

```
class CustomerActionListener implements ActionListener
{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)event.getSource();
    .. do something
  }
}
```

Which causes the following compiler warning in jdk7:

**JComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox should be parameterized**

I've tried to parameterize it to  such that:

```
JComboBox<String> cb = (JComboBox<String>)event.getSource();
```

But this still leaves the following compiler warning:

**Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to JComboBox**

*Therefore I'm not sure how to eliminate the compiler warnings...*

Comment: Does an instanceof check help? Even if you know you're always going to get a JComboBox at the end.

Comment: I don't think you "code" a solution to solve the problem.  You  can, how ever, suppress the warnings. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593996/how-to-suppress-java-compiler-warnings-for-specific-functions. The problem is the compiler looks at the `ActionEvent.getSource` and says "I have an Object and while in theory, you can cast me, what you are trying to cast me to might not work"

Comment: I understand that you can suppress the warning, but that's less than ideal for me. If I did that to all compiler warnings, well let's just say it wouldn't be good. It's always better to find out why and properly solve it if at all possible.

Comment: generics in the ui ... are a nuisance, nothing more. Here you need to cast the source anyway, whether that's further typed or not doesn't really matter (as long as the do-stuff doesn't rely on a particular data type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apreciate this approach. It avoids any Typecasts and is easy to read.

I improved my answer, now It doesn't give you Compiler Warnings. The Type of JComboBox is now set to String. To get the selected Item, you have to go through the ComboBoxModel.

```
class CustomerActionListener implements ActionListener
{
  private JComboBox<String> comboBox;
  public CustomerActionListener(JComboBox<String> comboBox){
    this.comboBox = comboBox;
  }
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    // Just use the comboBox
    ComboBoxModel<String> model = comboBox.getModel();
    int index = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
    String choosen = model.getElementAt(index);
    System.out.println("Hey you choose "+choosen);
  }
}
```

Comment: And how will this help to get rid of the *JComboBox is a raw type. References to generic type JComboBox should be parameterized* warning. Your code has exactly the same problem

Comment: Try to compile that code with JDK7-->You still have the compiler warning! Your answer does not solve the problem as it stands.

Comment: Thanks Robin and Guillaume. Made some changes. First I forgot to set the type on JComboBox. Next I thought a typed JComboBox could return a typed a Typed Result easier by just calling getSelectedItem(). But it can't. Now it should work just fine. Im not getting any compilerwarnings.

Answer (score 1):

The only way out here is to grab a typed reference to your `JComboBox`:

Either like this

```
JComboBox<String> myStringCb = new JComboBox<String>();
...
myStringCb.addActionListener(new CustomerActionListener(myStringCb);
```

and with you `ActionListener`:

```
class CustomerActionListener implements ActionListener {

  private JComboBox<String> cb;

  public CustomerActionListener(JComboBox<String> cb) {
    this.cb = cb;
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource()==cb) {
       // Here you can do something with the typed cb
    }
  }
}
```

Or, another solution is to use an anonymous `ActionListener` with a `final` reference:

```
final JComboBox<String> myStringCb = new JComboBox<String>();
myStringCb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Here you can refer directly to myStringCb
    }

});
```

Comment: ehh ... that's quite contradictory to the basic idea of an Action (which is one-to-many :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Nothing prevents you from making this one-to-many. In this example, I exposed the basic concept and a one-to-one relationship. But as you indicated in another post, the typing of the UI element is kind of pointless. It should not go further than the model.

Comment: _Nothing prevents you from making this one-to-many._ Nothing except ... keeping a list of targets? I don't think that's a viable option, at the end we at least agree on the kind-of pointlessness of generics in the view realm :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this:

[A very useful link form StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592642/type-safety-unchecked-cast-from-object)

In few words, Java compiler don't know what object is the one you're trying to cast, so it don't like to do the cast without a word, it must advise you that you maybe are making a mistake (but you DO know what kind of Class is the Object you are casting, so don't mind about it) Add a @SuppressWarning("unchecked")

Comment: @stephane (written by Meriton). So you don't need to add suppress warning ;)
You can write:

Class<? extends Action<ClientInterface>> c = ClientAction.class;
Action<ClientInterface> action = c.newInstance();
This eliminates both the cast and the warning, at the price of introducing a non-generic type so you can use .class to get a sufficiently accurately typed Class object.

Answer (score 0):

**Yet another solution**

You can also use the [Java Wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_(Java)) pattern:

```
class CustomerActionListener implements ActionListener
{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    JComboBox<?> cb = (JComboBox<?>)event.getSource();
    .. do something
  }
}
```