# When might a clone not be the type of the original object?

Tags: java, clone, compiler-warnings

I have a class that stores certain events and gives out clones, but Eclipse (my IDE) gives me unchecked clone warnings:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public PlayerEvents {

    private final ArrayList<KeyEvent> keyevents;
    private final ArrayList<MouseEvent> mouseevents;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // I have to do this to keep the IDE quiet
    public PlayerEvents(ArrayList<KeyEvent> keyevents, ArrayList<MouseEvent> mouseevents) {
        this.keyevents = (ArrayList<KeyEvent>) keyevents.clone(); // Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<KeyEvent>
        this.mouseevents = (ArrayList<MouseEvent>) mouseevents.clone(); // Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<KeyEvent>
    }

    // More code...

}
```

When would a cloned object **not** be its source, i.e. when will a cloned `keyevent` not be the type of `keyevent`?

**Edit:** Furthermore, why does the .clone() object give an Object? Does this have to do with the limitations of the Java language?

I'm using Eclipse Mars (4.5.2) with Java 1.8.0_91.

Comment: Um, I think only if the `clone()` implementation is broken.  The JVM does the clone itself and guarantees that the objects are the same type.

Comment: I think it's broken too. It worked for me when using a matrix of int, however, I recently had to create a clone of a matrix of a class I myself created and it did not work. I had to create it and copy each value 1 by 1.

Comment: I think the problem is that the parameter in your constructor is referred to as an `ArrayList<KeyEvent>`, but it could be something else wrongly cast into an `ArrayList<KeyEvent>`, for example a non-generic `List` that can contain anything. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2693301/5221346).

Comment: Hmm, my IDE doesn't give that warning.  I think maybe Eclipse is being a little over zealous here. (I'm also using Java 8, maybe Java 7 can't fully recognize the type conversion there? What version of Java are you using?)

Comment: Java 1.8; added version to question

Comment: *thou shalt not use `.clone()`; tis a wicked and evil thing to do*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because during the runtime JVM can not ensure that clone method() will return a `ArrayList<MouseEvent>` because of the [type ereasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Talking about the clone method, you must attent to the following:

> By default, java cloning is ‘field by field copy’ i.e. as the Object
>   class does not have idea about the structure of class on which clone()
>   method will be invoked. So, JVM when called for cloning, do following
>   things:
>
> 1) If the class has only primitive data type members then a completely
>   new copy of the object will be created and the reference to the new
>   object copy will be returned.
>
> 2) If the class contains members of any class type then only the
>   object references to those members are copied and hence the member
>   references in both the original object as well as the cloned object
>   refer to the same object.

[Here's the best clone explanation I've ever found. Quick and direct.](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` returns a type `Object`.  It will always be the same type as the `ArrayList`, but you still have to cast.  It's a syntax thing.

C.f. [ArrayList.clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone--)

Regarding your second question: yes, originally in Java method return values could not be co-variant.  You had to return the exact type as the overridden method.  Hence, `Object.clone()` could only return type `Object` and that's what its overridden methods must do also.