# How to deal with an overload resolution ambiguity of functions with generics?

Tags: generics, kotlin, ambiguous, overload-resolution

Consider this class with two functions, one with `Int` argument, the other with a generic one:

```
class C<K, V> {
    // ...

    operator fun f(index: Int): Pair<K, V> = ...
    operator fun f(key: K): V = ...
}
```

When it is parameterized as `C<Int, SomeType>`, `K` is `Int`, and both functions match the calls, resulting into an error:

```
val m = C<Int, SomeType>()
m.f(1)
```

> Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match:
>
> - `public final fun f(index: Int): SomeType` defined in `C`
> - `public final fun f(key: Int): Pair<Int, SomeType>?` defined in `C`

**How do I call whichever `f` I want in this case?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are lucky enough to have different parameter names of the functions, using [named arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments) will do the trick:

```
m.f(index = 1) // calls f(index: Int)
m.f(key = 1)   // calls f(key: K)
```

Otherwise, if the parameter names are the same (or defined in Java), one possible workaround is to perform [unchecked casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693180/what-is-unchecked-cast-and-how-do-i-check-it) to make the compiler choose the desired option:

- To call `f(index: Int)`, you can use

  ```
  @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
  val s = (m as C<*, SomeType>).f(1) as Pair<Int, SomeType>
  ```

  The cast to `C<*, SomeType>` [makes `K` equivalent to `in Nothing, out Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections), meaning that there's no valid argument for `f(key: K)`, so the call is naturally resolved to `f(index: Int)`, but you need to cast the result back, because otherwise it is `Pair<Any, SomeType>`.
- To call `f(key: K)`, use:

  ```
  @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
  val s = (m as C<Any, SomeType>).f(1 as Any)
  ```

  Similarly, the cast to `C<Any, SomeType>` changes the signature of the desired function to `f(key: Any)`, and to call it, just upcast `1` to `Any`.

It's all the same in case of several type parameters clashing (e.g. `f(key: K)` and `f(value: V)` when `K` and `V` are both `SomeType`), just use named arguments or cast the object to *ban* one of the functions (`in Nothing`) or to make it accept `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin stdlib uses convention `fun fAt(index: Int)` to resolve such cases.

Comment: That's true, but that requires some thought in advance to design class `C` preventing possible signature clashes with substituted generics. And if you faced such class and have no way to rename its functions, you have to resort to generic tricks from @hotkey's answer.