# Kotlin compiler's type inference can't choose which method to call (ambiguity with generic types)

Tags: generics, kotlin, overloading, kotlin-interop

So, I have some Java methods with these signatures (removed annotations and code body for the sake of simplicity):

```
public class JavaClass {
  public static <E extends CharSequence> E join(E... array) { ... }
  public static <E extends CharSequence> E join(CharSequence separator, E... array) { ... }
}
```

And I have some code in Kotlin, which calls the 'join' method:

```
class KtClass {
    fun test(vararg array: String) {
        JavaClass.join(*array)
    }
}
```

So far so good; it will spread the varargs and call the former method signature. Okie dokie!

The problem comes if, for example, I want to call the latter method signature, with a 'separator' argument:

```
class KtClass {
    fun test(vararg array: String) {
        JavaClass.join("<br>", *array)
    }
}
```

This code won't compile. The compiler can't get to decide which method to call. The error:

> Error:(5, 13) Kotlin: Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference: 
>   public open fun  join(vararg array: String!): String! defined in JavaClass
>   public open fun  join(separator: CharSequence!, vararg array: String!): String! defined in JavaClass

I can't even name the arguments because Kotlin doesn't let argument naming for non-Kotlin functions.

**EDIT:** Replaced the *E* generic type parameter with plain *String* references in the Java method headers, and it worked! So I guess this to be an incompatibility of type inference with generic types or something like that?

---

---

I'm pretty sure this has to be something with the **spread operator** (*). But I can't pass the varargs parameter `array` to the `join` function if I don't use it.

How can I solve this without touching the Java code?

*YES, I KNOW that there is Array.joinToString extension function, but this would solve only this particular case. I need to know a generic solution.*

Comment: Please check if the unchecked casts described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722976/how-to-deal-with-an-overload-resolution-ambiguity-of-functions-with-generics) can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's Kotlin specific. The problem is that the generic argument, `E` is of type `CharSequence` so your call becomes something like `join("separator", "word1", "word2")` which is, indeed, ambiguous since the first argument, of type `E == CharSequence` is the same as the type of the other args.

Comment: But this ambiguity doesn't happen with the Java compiler... I can call `JavaClass.join("some separator", someArray)` and it will select the correct method.

Comment: And I can see why that happens because of the spread operator... but, AFAIK, it is the only way to pass a Kotlin varargs parameter to a Java method receiving varargs

Comment: I **think** what's happening here is that the spread operator de-sugars to `join("a", "b", "c")` rather than `join("a", arrayOfOtherArgs)` so it's not the same as the Java call. Doesn't this work `join("<br>", array)`? I don't have the same libs available but to test I did this and it worked: `  val varargs = arrayOf("a", "b", "c'")` and then `String.format("my format string: %s", varargs)`. In other words, as far as i can tell you can pass a Kotlin array to a varargs method without the spread operator.

Comment: AFAIK, yes, a Kotlin array can be passed to a varargs method without the spread operator, but a Kotlin varargs method parameter can't, and here's where the problem lies... as you said, it is "de-sugaring" and since the separator is of the same type as the array elements, it does not know which method to call

Comment: Interesting. I see what you mean. Sorry, don't have an answer. BTW, note that my `String.format` example was flawed as `String.format`'s varargs are of type `Object` so it's just passing that whole array as a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will need to create a helper class in Java to bridge the interop issue. e.g.:

```
public class JavaClassInterop {
    public static <E extends CharSequence> E joinSeparatedBy(CharSequence separator,
                                                             E... array) {
        return JavaClass.join(separator, array);
    }
}
```

Then you can call both:

```
import JavaClass.join
import JavaClassInterop.joinSeparatedBy

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    join(*args)
    joinSeparatedBy("<br>", *args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tldr

**Probably you work incorrectly with nullable types**

I was struggling with this error for a while, but finally came up with a solution. I had this at first

```
user.items.apply {
        removeAll(otherItems)
        removeAll(otherItems2)
    }
```

The items collection is a MutableSet? so it is nullable, and otherItems collections are nullable too. 
So after adding ? before the apply, and passing non nullable collection to the removeAll function, the errors disappeared.

```
user.items?.apply {
        removeAll(otherItems.orEmpty())
        removeAll(otherItems2.orEmpty())
    }
```