# Ambiguous overloaded method reference when using Any

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have an issue where I want to use a generic type, and the type has overloaded methods with a Collection and varargs. When I use *Any* as type parameter, I cant pass in a List as argument.

```
    val productType = ComboBox<Any>("Product type")
//    public void setItems(Collection<T> items) {
//    public void setItems(T... items) {
    productType.setItems(listOf("1","2")) // Not possible
```

Is there any better solution besides converting the list to an array via: `productType.setItems(*listOf("1","2").toTypedArray())`

Edit:
Working example to try out:

```
   class Foo<T>() {
        fun setItems(items: Collection<T>) {}
        fun setItems(vararg items: T) {}
    }
        val f = Foo<Any>()
        f.setItems(listOf("1", "2"))
```

Comment: What if you use `ComboBox<String>`?

Comment: How about `ComboBox<*>` ?

Comment: `ComboBox<String>` works of course. The issue seems to be the `Any`, since it could also mean `ComboBox<List<Any>>`, thus leading to the ambiguity. `ComboBox<*>` is not possible.

Comment: Can you show your ComboBox class declaration and the declaration of `setItems(Collection)`? I tried creating my own, and it worked fine.

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04, the class is from Vaadin and the the methods are as posted in the comment. Maybe the issue is related to the class bein a java class? Edit: no it's not. Added Working example to description.

Comment: How is the class declared? What are the bounds of the generic type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to call the overload that accepts a `Collection<T>` (for example, it has some desired side effects that the other one doesn't have), then there's a solution that tells the compiler to do that.

This is similar to: [How to deal with an overload resolution ambiguity of functions with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722976/how-to-deal-with-an-overload-resolution-ambiguity-of-functions-with-generics)

Basically, you can make an [unchecked cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unchecked-casts) that would limit the type argument of `ComboBox` so that `List<String>` no longer matches the signature with a vararg of the argument type and there's only the signature accepting the `Collection` that matches.

For that, you need to choose a new type argument, say `R`, that satisfies both:

- `List<R>` is not a subtype of `R`
- `List<R>` is still a subtype of `Collection<R>`

One can note that a type that we can use as `R` is `String`, giving this:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
(productType as ComboBox<String>).setItems(listOf("1","2"))
```

However, if the behavior of the two overloads is identical, it's simpler to pass an array to the vararg overload using `*list.toTypedArray()`, just as you mentioned.

Comment: I ended up with a solution utilizing both answers:
```
    fun <T>setProductTypeItems(productTypes: List<T>) {
        (productType as ComboBox<T>).setItems(productTypes)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extension method calling the desired overload without ambiguity:

```
fun <T> ComboBox<T>.setCollection(items: Collection<T>) { this.setItems(items) }
```

and then

```
productType.setCollection(listOf("1","2"))
```

Comment: Thanks, you answer helped me to figure out a solution without extension function.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```java
fun <T>setProductTypeItems(productTypes: List<T>) {
    (productType as ComboBox<T>).setItems(productTypes)
}
```