# Why is usage of the (erased) generic type in right-hand side allowed during type casting in Java?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, type-systems

This is disallowed, which I believe is due to type erasure. (`T` is erased and cannot be accessed in runtime to read its class like `T.class`).

```java
class Cup<T> {
    private T t;
    public T[] getArray(int size) {
        Class<T> cls = T.class;
        return (T[]) Array.newInstance(cls, size);
    }
}
```

But how come this compiles? I thought the type conversion of `(T)val` would happen at runtime, thus the JVM would know nothing about if `T` is `String` or anything else. So javac should prevent the program from being compiled at all. would error out.

```java
public class Cup<T> {
    public T get() {
        Integer val = 1;
        T result = (T)val;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cup<String> cup = new Cup<>();
        System.out.println(cup.get());
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything on compile time vs runtime? Why this design choice? What is the intuition behind that?

Comment: It compiles because you a performing an unchecked cast. If you run the program, you'll see that it results in a `ClassCastException` because an `Integer` cannot be casted to a `String`.

Comment: It compiles... but with a warning. Doesn't it? That warning tells you there's potential for trouble. Read through [What is unchecked cast and how do I check it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693180/what-is-unchecked-cast-and-how-do-i-check-it/2693301)

Comment: @JacobG. Yeah I noticed the warning, but my point is how come the erasured `String` type info is "reified" i the second example during the cast, but not in the first example Previously I thought the second would fail the compilation.

Comment: You can not guarantee the type of `T.class` at runtime, it can be anything. But when you create `Cup<String>`, it is known at compile-time and it won't change at runtime.

Comment: Can you explain what you understand about why the first code snippet is disallowed, and exactly why you don't think the second code snippet should be allowed? There should be a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat `Cup<String>` is known at compile time, but the conversion of `(T)val` is at runtime I suppose? Then how come the JVM knows `T` is now `String` instead of `Object`?

Comment: No, the compiler typecast it at compile time. There is no information available at runtime. If you have a bytecode decoder then you can verify it. Intellij Ultimate has a bytecode decoder, not sure about the community version.

Comment: @Sweeper Edited my post. I think there might be something wrong in my understanding of compile time vs runtime with regard to type conversion.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Would you mind elaborating on "typecast it at compile time". Are you referring to `(T)val` being performed at compile time, or `Cup<String>` becoming `Cup`?

Comment: Both of them are done at compile time. `(T) val` becomes `(String) val` and `Cup<String>` becomes `Cup`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat So if I have many instances of the generics, say `Cup<String>`, `Cup<Integer>`, etc. There will be many different versions of typecast code generated during compile time for `(T) val`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would recommend you download a bytecode decoder to understand it completely.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Sure. By the way, would you mind reorg your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? Also I would appreciate if you can link to the spec where this semantic is officially specified, and explain the intuition about how the type system works here. (Sorry if I'm asking for too much).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6 would be a nice starting point. You can accept the answer by sweeper, it has a lot of information and I would consider that you accepted my answer if you accept sweeper's :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228333/discussion-between-wlnirvana-and-aniket-sahrawat).

Answer (score 1):

This is called an *unchecked narrowing reference conversion* by the [Java Lanaguage Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.2).  Allowing these casts is important for building some generic code.  For example, they are used widely in implementing `ArrayList`, where the elements are stored in an `Object[]` and so static type checking is lost as items are added to and retrieved from the underlying array.  However, because the compiler cannot perform the check statically nor at runtime, use of these conversions results in an *unchecked warning*:

> If a narrowing reference conversion is unchecked, then the Java Virtual Machine will not be able to fully validate its type correctness, possibly leading to heap pollution. To flag this to the programmer, an unchecked narrowing reference conversion causes a compile-time unchecked warning, unless suppressed by @SuppressWarnings

These conversions exist solely in source code; they are not compiled into the bytecode and have no effect on the runtime.  They are required solely to force the programmer to declare that they know (better than the compiler) that the conversion is safe.

Comment: To sum up, the java language designers could have chosen checked cast here, in which case compilation would fail due to `T` being lost at runtime, just like in my first example. However, they opted for "unchecked narrowing reference" in this case, for the benefit like how `(E) elementData[index]` is used in `ArrayList` implementation. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that "the JVM would know nothing about if `T` is `String` or anything else", and as a result *nothing will happen at runtime*.

Normally, the runtime evaluation of a (reference type) cast would involve *checking* whether the object that you are casting *actually* is of the type that you are casting to. For example:

```
Object o = new Object();
String s = (String)o;
```

At runtime, a check is performed on `o`, and it will be found that `o` is actually of type `Object` and not `String`, and as such, a `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

On the other hand, if you are casting to a type parameter `T`, the runtime has no idea what `T` is, and so does not do any checking, hence this is an "unchecked cast", as the warning says.

So if `val` isn't actually of type `T`, no exceptions will be thrown:

```
Cup<String> c = new Cup<>();
c.get();
```

Even though I called `get` in the above code, and the line with the cast is executed, there will be no exceptions, because there is no runtime check. The runtime thinks that `get` returns an `Object`. It is *only* when the runtime knows what type to cast, does the cast happen, and the exception get thrown:

```
Cup<String> c = new Cup<>();
String s = c.get(); // this throws an exception
```

The compiler inserts the cast in the second line like so `String s = (String)c.get();`

As you can see, it doesn't really matter that the runtime doesn't know what `T` is at the line where the cast is, because you don't *need* the cast there anyway. Consider the type-erased version of your code:

```
public class Cup {
    public Object get() {
        Integer val = 1;
        Object result = val;
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cup cup = new Cup();
        System.out.println(cup.get());
    }
}
```

You'll notice that this is perfectly fine code that will compile!

`(T)val` here is mostly here to make the compiler happy, to convince the compiler that `val` is indeed of type `T`.

Comment: Interesting. I found that while `c.get();` runs without exception as you stated, `c.get().getClass();` actually has the `checkcast <java/lang/String>` instruction generated and throws an exception at runtime. But note that no `String` is explicitly written by the programmer in this statement! This means the javac type system is actually capable of deducing that `c.get()` is returning `String` rather than `Object`, but the language designers deliberately chose not to statically check the cast when only `c.get()` is called.

Comment: And I feel the more intuitive (i.e. for people without deep knowledge of how casting and type erasure work) explanation for this exception lies in neither `c.get().getClass()` nor `Cup<String> c = new Cup<>();`, but in `T result = (T)val;` being allowed. That is, the cast check should not be delayed to `c.get().getClass()` or even `c.get()`, but should have been handled in `(T) val` by failing this line at compile time.

Comment: @wlnirvana Your first comment is correct. What the compiler _can't_ do is to insert a check at the `(T)val` line, because the runtime doesn't know what `T` is. Regarding your second comment, the compiler _could_ be designed to not allow this kind of unchecked casts, but then it would make a lot of code very hard/impossible to write. I'm not one of the language designers, but I think they possibly weighed the costs and benefits of this, and concluded that it's better to allow this.

Comment: @wlnirvana Think of it this way. You are the designer and you want that the code written in java 4 should be compatible/compilable with/in java 14. How would you design it? Stress on it and you will find your answers without anybody's help.