# Kotlin delegate's ReadOnlyProperty with generic type value dose not cast correctly in getValue

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-delegate

I am expecting to see the output

```
black
white
```

with below code

```
package delegate

import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

open class Color(private val name: String) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return name
    }
}

class Black : Color("black")
class White : Color("white")

class ColorCollection {
    private val black = Black()
    private val white = White()
    val list = listOf(black, white)
}

class Palette {
    val black: Black by ColorDelegate()
    val white: White by ColorDelegate()
    val colorCollection = ColorCollection()
}

class ColorDelegate<T> : ReadOnlyProperty<Palette, T> {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Palette, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return thisRef.colorCollection.list.mapNotNull { it as? T }.first()
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val palette = Palette()
    println(palette.black)
    println(palette.white)
}
```

However, I only get black output and then `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: delegate.Black cannot be cast to delegate.White`.
I found that with this line `thisRef.colorCollection.list.mapNotNull { it as? T }`, I am expecting it only returns the value in the list that can be safely cast to the generic type, otherwise return null. For example, when accessing black delegated property in Palette, I should only see 1 black element returned by `thisRef.colorCollection.list.mapNotNull { it as? T }`,It actually returns two (black and white). `it as? T` somehow always works regardless of what T is. I also tried putting a breakpoint at that line, tried "abcdef" as T?, it also works, which I expect to see cast exception that String cannot be cast to Black...
[image][image]

Is this a bug...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that [Type Erasure](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/type-erasure/14519/3) is a thing in Kotlin, so the runtime does not know what the `T` in `it as? T`, and hence cannot check the cast for you. Therefore, the cast always succeeds (and something else will fail later down the line). See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693180/what-is-unchecked-cast-and-how-do-i-check-it). IntelliJ should have given you an "unchecked cast" warning here.

So rather than checking the type using `T`, you can check the type using the `property` argument:

```
class ColorDelegate<T> {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Palette, property: KProperty<*>) =
        // assuming such an item always exists
        thisRef.colorCollection.list.first { 
            property.returnType.classifier == it::class 
        } as T
}

fun main()  {
    val palette = Palette()
    println(palette.black) // prints "black"
    println(palette.white) // prints "white"
}
```

Here, I've checked that the class of the `returnType` of the property (i.e. the property on which you are putting the delegate) is equal to the list element's runtime class. You can also e.g. be more lenient and check `isSubclassOf`.

Do note that this wouldn't find any element in the list if the property's type was another type parameter, rather than a class, e.g.

```
class Palette<T> {
    ...
    val foo: T by ColorDelegate()
    ...
}
```

But alas, that's type erasure for you :(

Comment: `property.returnType.classifier == it::class`. Thank you, this works for me!!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to type erasure with generics. Casting to a generic type always succeeds because generic types are not known at runtime. This can cause a runtime exception elsewhere if the value is assigned to a variable of a concrete mismatched type or a function it doesn't have is called on it.

Since casting to generic types is dangerous (it silently works, allowing for bugs that occur at a different place in code), there is a compiler warning when you do it like in your code. The warning says "unchecked cast" because the cast occurs without type-checking. When you cast to a concrete type, the runtime checks the type at the cast site and if there is a mismatch it immediately throws ClassCastException, or resolves to null in the case of a safe-cast `as?`.

[Info about type erasure in the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure)