# Best way to store SparseBooleanArray in Bundle?

Tags: android, methods, onconfigurationchanged, sparse-array

When a config change happens, my ListView Checkbox states get lost, which I understand why.
I try to implement

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState)
```

in one of my Fragments. So I'm just wondering what's the easiest way to store my SparseBooleanArray in the *outState*.

Also, I'm a bit confused, as ListView has the method:

```
getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
```

What's this good for?

Comment: You might not need to use `onSaveInstanceState()` at all. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294919/maintain-item-selection-on-orientation-change

Answer (score 40):

In my case, I ended up doing it by implementing a Parcelable wrapper around the SparseBooleanArray, like this:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;

public class SparseBooleanArrayParcelable extends SparseBooleanArray implements Parcelable {
  public static Parcelable.Creator<SparseBooleanArrayParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SparseBooleanArrayParcelable>() {
    @Override
    public SparseBooleanArrayParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
      SparseBooleanArrayParcelable read = new SparseBooleanArrayParcelable();
      int size = source.readInt();

      int[] keys = new int[size];
      boolean[] values = new boolean[size];

      source.readIntArray(keys);
      source.readBooleanArray(values);

      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        read.put(keys[i], values[i]);
      }

      return read;
    }

    @Override
    public SparseBooleanArrayParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
      return new SparseBooleanArrayParcelable[size];
    }
  };

  public SparseBooleanArrayParcelable() {

  }

  public SparseBooleanArrayParcelable(SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sparseBooleanArray.size(); i++) {
      this.put(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i), sparseBooleanArray.valueAt(i));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    int[] keys = new int[size()];
    boolean[] values = new boolean[size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
      keys[i] = keyAt(i);
      values[i] = valueAt(i);
    }

    dest.writeInt(size());
    dest.writeIntArray(keys);
    dest.writeBooleanArray(values);
  }
}
```

This allows you to save and load your SparseBooleanArray by just doing:

```
Bundle bundle; //For your activity/fragment state, to include in an intent, ...
SparseBooleanArray sbarray; //Probably from your listview.getCheckedItemPositions()

//Write it
bundle.putParcelable("myBooleanArray", new SparseBooleanArrayParcelable(sbarray));

//Read it back
sbarray = (SparseBooleanArray) bundle.getParcelable("myBooleanArray");
```

Just my .02€

Comment: You should cast bundle.getParcelable("myBooleanArray") to (SparseBooleanArray) when reading from Bundle.

Comment: `Parcel` class has `writeSparseBooleanArray` and `readSparseBooleanArray` instead of writing the read and write manually

Comment: @MohamedKamalKamaly as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeSparseBooleanArray(android.util.SparseBooleanArray)) that method is not even in a released version of the API while this answer has already four years. Anyway, I wouldn't jump too quickly into using those new methods just yet if I were you...

Comment: wops, just realized I was looking at the wrong method there :P

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any answers to the last part of the question:

> Also, I'm a bit confused, as ListView has the method:
>
> `getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();`
>
> What's this good for?

Assuming you're using checkboxes in conjunction with Action Mode, the Action Mode itself will store the state of checked positions. In the normal mode, a press-and-hold will highlight an item, enable action mode, and then allow the user to tap other items to also check them.

What happens on an orientation change? Action mode is resumed and the highlights are kept. Your checkboxes aren't, but clearly the data of what is checked is.

After an orientation change, `onCreateActionMode()` is called. In this method (but not before), `getListView().getCheckedItemPositions()` will return the `SparseBooleanArray` you're probably looking for.

The nifty part about this is if this is your only use case for the `SparseBooleanArray`, you need not even worry about storing it yourself. You can retrieve it from the system which is *already* storing it across the orientation change.

That's what `getListView().getCheckedItemPositions()` is good for.

Answer (score 2):

You could either invent some serialization scheme for that data structure or switch to a HashSet and store only the list index positions in it which are checked. Since HashSet is serializable you can just put it into the instance state Bundle.

Comment: thanks, in my case it was easier than creating additional classes

Comment: HashMap<Integer,Boolean> would be a better alternative to SparseBooleanArray than HashSet

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do the same thing.  Initially i was using a `HashMap`

[How to send hashmap value to another activity using an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578236/how-to-send-hashmap-value-to-another-activity-using-an-intent)

to pass between activities since it extends the `Serializable` interface.  However, after doing some research:

"`SparseBooleanArrays` are intended to be more efficient than using a `HashMap` to map `Integers` to `Booleans`."

However, I can't find a simple way to store this data structure.  I have contemplated grabbing the values of the `SparseBooleanArray` and storing it in a `HashMap` so that it can be passed between activities.  But this seems to add more complexity.

Unfortunately, I think I am going to revert to using HashMaps to store my list of checked boxes

Answer (score 1):

Extend SparseArray to implement a Serializable:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import android.util.SparseArray;



/**
 * @author Asaf Pinhassi www.mobiledev.co.il
 * @param <E>
 *
 */
public class SerializableSparseArray<E> extends SparseArray<E> implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 824056059663678000L;

    public SerializableSparseArray(int capacity){
        super(capacity);
    }

    public SerializableSparseArray(){
        super();
    }

    /**
     * This method is private but it is called using reflection by java
     * serialization mechanism. It overwrites the default object serialization.
     *
     * <br/><br/><b>IMPORTANT</b>
     * The access modifier for this method MUST be set to <b>private</b> otherwise {@link java.io.StreamCorruptedException}
     * will be thrown.
     *
     * @param oos
     *            the stream the data is stored into
     * @throws IOException
     *             an exception that might occur during data storing
     */
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
        Object[] data = new  Object[size()];

        for (int i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            Object[] pair = {keyAt(i),valueAt(i)}; 
            data[i] = pair;
        }
        oos.writeObject(data);
    }

    /**
     * This method is private but it is called using reflection by java
     * serialization mechanism. It overwrites the default object serialization.
     *
     * <br/><br/><b>IMPORTANT</b>
     * The access modifier for this method MUST be set to <b>private</b> otherwise {@link java.io.StreamCorruptedException}
     * will be thrown.
     *
     * @param oos
     *            the stream the data is read from
     * @throws IOException
     *             an exception that might occur during data reading
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     *             this exception will be raised when a class is read that is
     *             not known to the current ClassLoader
     */
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Object[] data = (Object[]) ois.readObject();
        for (int i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            Object[] pair = (Object[]) data[i]; 
            this.append((Integer)pair[0],(E)pair[1]);
        }
        return;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `Parcelable` holder class, using the native methods from `Parcel` in order to serialize/deserialize the `SparseBooleanArray`:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;

public class SparseBooleanArrayHolder implements Parcelable {

    private final SparseBooleanArray source;

    public SparseBooleanArrayHolder(SparseBooleanArray source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public SparseBooleanArray get() {
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeSparseBooleanArray(source);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<SparseBooleanArrayHolder> CREATOR = new Creator<SparseBooleanArrayHolder>() {
        @Override
        public SparseBooleanArrayHolder createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SparseBooleanArrayHolder(in.readSparseBooleanArray());
        }

        @Override
        public SparseBooleanArrayHolder[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SparseBooleanArrayHolder[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Just a simple wrapper that can be used to serialise a `SparseBooleanArray`.

```
public class SerializableSparseBooleanArrayContainer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 393662066105575556L;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSparseArray;

    public SerializableSparseBooleanArrayContainer(SparseBooleanArray mDataArray) {
        this.mSparseArray = mDataArray;
    }

    public SparseBooleanArray getSparseArray() {
        return mSparseArray;
    }

    public void setSparseArray(SparseBooleanArray sparseArray) {
        this.mSparseArray = sparseArray;
    }

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeLong(serialVersionUID);
        int sparseArraySize = mSparseArray.size();
        out.write(sparseArraySize);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < sparseArraySize; i++){
            int key = mSparseArray.keyAt(i);
            out.writeInt(key);
            boolean value = mSparseArray.get(key);
            out.writeBoolean(value);
        }
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        long readSerialVersion = in.readLong();
        if (readSerialVersion != serialVersionUID) {
            throw new IOException("serial version mismatch");
        }
        int sparseArraySize = in.read();
        mSparseArray = new SparseBooleanArray(sparseArraySize);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < sparseArraySize; i++) {
            int key = in.readInt();
            boolean value = in.readBoolean();
            mSparseArray.put(key, value);
        }
    }

}
```

I then add the object to a bundle like so:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = getSparseBooleanArray();
    SerializableSparseBooleanArrayContainer sparseBooleanArraySerializable = new SerializableSparseBooleanArrayContainer(sparseBooleanArray);
    outState.putSerializable(SOME_BUNDLE_KEY, sparseBooleanArraySerializable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution creating `SerializableSparseArray` extending `SparseArray` making it possible to put a `SparseArray` into bundle via `Bundle.putSerializable` call.

But I found I can't obtain the saved object from bundle in `onRestoreInstanceState`. Digging into the issue I found that `savedInstanceState.getSerializable(KEY_TO_STRING_SPARSE_ARRAY) == null`.

Then, trying to inspect `savedInstanceState.get(KEY_TO_STRING_SPARSE_ARRAY)` and suprisingly got a `SparseArray<String>` not `SerializableSparseArray<String>`. Finally I'm using `savedInstanceState.getSparseParcelableArray(KEY_TO_STRING_SPARSE_ARRAY)` to obtaining `SparseArray` back from a bundle.

Then, using java reflection to save a `SparseArray<String>` to bundle directly without extending with `Serializable` or `Parcelable` interface. It's a little bit dirty but I think you can make your own utility function hiding the following detail implementation.

```
try {
    // FIXME WTF
    Method m = Bundle.class.getMethod("putSparseParcelableArray", String.class, SparseArray.class);
    m.invoke(savedInstanceState, KEY_TO_STRING_SPARSE_ARRAY, mSparseStringArray);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
}
```

I've tested the code and it works on Android 4.4.4. And I'd like to know if it's safe to use the implementation in other SDK implementations.