# Get HashMap data from another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, hashmap

I have used [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) to save session. I still don't understand how to get this data from another activity.

```
 public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
      user.put(KEY_FULLNAME, pref.getString(KEY_FULLNAME, null));        
      user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

    // return user
    return user;
}
```

I found out people are using intent to send it to another activity like in this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578236/how-to-send-hashmap-value-to-another-activity-using-an-intent) Is there a simple way to get the data like i call methods from another activity(import the class, then give a variable `var` for that class, and call the method like `var.theMethodFromClass()`).

---

Update

```
public SessionManager(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}
```

this function is in my SessionManager class, how can i use it directly, without initializing all variables again, as they are already initialized in the activity in order to be used.

*the full code of SessionManager.class is in the first link*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already saved your data in the `SharedPrefernces` so why you need to send it from one `Activity` to another `Activity`..Try to open the `SharedPreference` file in Another Activity and Use it as you like..

Comment: `SharedPreferences pref; String name = pref.getString(KEY_FULLNAME, null);` like this?

but i have to initialize `pref`

Comment: yes..and initialize the preference with the same file name as you mentioned in Activity1..you have to use the same key for retrieving the data..

Answer (score 1):

Save data to preferences in calling activity.

```
public void saveToPreferences(HashMap<String, String> user)
{
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString(KEY_FULLNAME, user.get(KEY_FULLNAME));
editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, user.get(KEY_EMAIL));
    editor.commit();
}
```

In your called activity.
use this code.
Initialize preferences 1st then get data from it.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    user.put(KEY_FULLNAME, pref.getString(KEY_FULLNAME, null));        
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));


    return user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the `HashMap` and use it even after the application is restarted, then use `SharedPreferences`. It will save the `HashMap` in the device.

If you just need to pass the `HashMap` as parameter to another `Activity`, use `Intent`. All that you pass by `Intent`'s must be serializable to work well in all cases. Read: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score -1):

Why would you pass a hashmap to an Activity? This makes **NO** Sense.

Take the data from the hashmap/preference and pass it in the extras from Activity A to Activity B. Stick to primitives when it comes to passing data between activities.

Answer (score -2):

If your project allows it, just make the HashMap **static** then you can retrieve it in any other activity in your project by calling **Class.hashmapvar**

Comment: It solve some cases, but it'll always be a huge source of bugs. To understand why it shouldn't be done, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541688/static-variable-null-when-returning-to-the-app

Comment: of course you have to do a null check... this should be a quick solution to the problem, I know there are other ways to handle this, I was just intending what could be done

Comment: A null check will just avoid a NullPointerException and you'll not get the HashMap you want (in some cases).