# After sending data to server how to print response in next activity?

Tags: android, json, android-listview, httpresponse

I am trying to send data to server and in response i am getting some data which i need to display in next activity using listview,can any one tell me how to do this?

Comment: use shared prefrences or a singleton class

Comment: what type of data you have to pass like : String,Object,List etc ?

Comment: i am sending data to server in text and getting response in text

Comment: In which format you are getting data? If `json`, you can send direct as `json.toString()`

Comment: You said you are sending text to server and getting text in response, that you want to send to next activity. So what about images now?

Comment: this question is asked many times in many different ways, please consider doing a search.

Answer (score 3):

use `bundle` to move your response from one activity to another

-create class that implements Parcelable

```
  public class ResponseData implements Parcelable{}
```

-Next save it in intent:

```
intent.putExtra(key, new ResponseData(someDataFromServer));
```

-Last step - retrive it:

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
ResponseData response= (ResponseData ) data.getParcelable(key);
```

After that add it to an adapter to display it for the user

In other case you can save it in application context or database (not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you to **pass necessary parameters to next activity** using `Bundle` and **from next activity itself you should make a call** to server to receive and display necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

- Send data to server using AsyncTask
- After getting result in doInBackground , continue with
  onPostexecute()
- Start the next activity in onPostexecute()

Comment: ok i am sending data using some fields like country,mother tongue,religion.it is kind of searching users list..and in response i will get user's name in list which i need to show in next activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578236/how-to-send-hashmap-value-to-another-activity-using-an-intent?answertab=oldest#tab-top           Is it ok for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an event bus library, such as greenrobot EventBus. With it, the process will be done in 4 lines of code:

(In sender Activity)

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
EventBus.getDeafult().postSticky(myDataObject);
```

(In receiving Activity)

```
DataObject passedData = EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(DataObject.class);
```

You will also need a POJO data class:

```
public static class DataObject{
    private String data;

    public String getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data){
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Clean, quick and elegant :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Send data to server
2. Get the response
3. Put that string as Extra in Intent and start activity

   > Intent i = new Intent(this, YourNextActivityName.class);
   >   i.putExtra("res",response.toString);
   >   i.startActivity();
4. On Next Activity get that Data and display.

   ```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
       String response= extras.getString("res");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

```
 1)Send data.
 2)Get Response
 3)if respose is ok, save that in a static string and fire intent and on the next 
   activity get the respose using classname.your string. simple and best way.
```