# Send data to MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

i have some latitude and logtitute i want to send these to MapActivity is it possible i did many ways but failled

```
public void setdaata(View view){
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMap.put("key", "value");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("map", item);
    startActivity(intent);




}
```

and receiving code in Mapacitivity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
    Log.v("HashMapTest", hashMap.get("key"));
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: what is the problem? it is not working? do you have any exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578236/how-to-send-hashmap-value-to-another-activity-using-an-intent

Answer (score 1):

So, perhaps you don't need a map here to send two simple values:

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("longitude", mLongitude);
intent.putExtra("latitude", mLatitude);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then to extract your values:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

double mLongitude = intent.getExtras().getDouble("longitude);
double mLatitude = intent.getExtras().getDouble("latitude");
```

Now you should have your values as needed!!

I hope this helps you!

Comment: sir but i have alot of values which i recieved through json this method i think work for just 2 values is there any way to send array to MApactivity

Comment: The best approach here would then be to store your data in a local database and then simply go to the next activity and query your database simply and display the data to the user. That is what I would do