# How do I get data from HashMap to pass to next Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, hashmap

I wish to pass data from one Listview activity to the next activity, i.e. when an item is clicked in the list, data such as the title or thumb_url (an image from a remote database) can be passed to a detail Activity.

In the example below, these items are set out in an `HashMap`.

What code will pass the above data to another activity, using an intent?

I'm puzzled because these data items are laid out in a `HashMap`.

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://padihamcars.com/music.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
}
```

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Comment: It's simpler than you expect. Just do the reverse of what you've done before `songsList.add(map);`.

Comment: Your question was unclear, possibly because you were not breaking it down to a more solvable task. Passing it to the Activity comes after you have got the object. Besides, you should use a [POJO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527264/how-to-create-a-pojo) to avoid messy code in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send hashmap value to another activity using an intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578236/how-to-send-hashmap-value-to-another-activity-using-an-intent)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :-**

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                        HashMap<String, String> map  = songsList.get(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("map", map);
                        startActivity(intent);

                }
```

**And than in the receiving Activity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
    Log.v("HashMapTest", hashMap.get("key"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if this will retrieve the values in the second activity, though - "key" is a bit vague..

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:Fetch the hashmap of a particular position from the list and then fetch the values using the keys.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    resultp   = songsList.get(position);
    String s_id=resultp.get(KEY_ID);
    String s_title=resultp.get(KEY_TITLE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("s_id", s_id);
    intent.putExtra("s_title", s_title);
    //other fields you want to send
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Define the arraylist: `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` globally.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll try it later. This looks like what I'm looking for!

Comment: Ok try it and if it work then dont forget to accept the answer.Happy coding :)

Comment: Oh, just one question - what will I need to define re:Hashmap<String in the second activity??

Comment: you dont need to define hashmap again in your secondactivity.You are getting the string values directly

Comment: Ah -thanks for that! Going to implement it today - too busy yesterday!