# How to fix InvocationTargetException when sending hashmap to other activity

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm trying to send HashMap to start new activity with `startActivity(intent).`

I followed the answer from this link:
[How to send hashmap value to another activity using an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578236/how-to-send-hashmap-value-to-another-activity-using-an-intent)

But I still get error

Of course, i tried to send String

```
intent.putExtra("test","some String");
startActivity(intent);
```

And it worked

My code:

```java
HashMap<String,Diner> dinersOrdersHasMap = new HashMap<String,Diner>();
FillHashMap(); // Fill the HashMap with data

Intent intent = new Intent(this, BillForm.class);
intent.putExtra("dinersOrderHashMap",dinersOrdersHasMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

The exception:

```java
   "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);

    e.detailMessage = "Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable 
    object (name = com.example.myfirstapp.Diner)
```

When i call 
`startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your Diner class Serializable or Parcelable ?

Could you post here your Diner class ?

Comment: You right! I changed ```class Diner implements Serializable ```