# How to fix code to remove -Xlint:unchecked warning while compiling

Tags: java, generics, compilation, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)

My program compiles and works correctly when I compile with -Xlint:unchecked, but I am looking for assistance to remove this warning.  Any help is appreciated! Thank you

This is the warning:

```
java: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
found   : E
required: java.lang.Comparable<E>

                            ^^^^
```

The code the gives the warning is:

```
public boolean contains(E obj) {

    Node<E> curr = head;

        while (curr != null) {
                return true;
            }

            curr = curr.next;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings

Comment: @PetrAbdulin in this case, it's not the same. This could end in a `ClassCastException` if the `E` class doesn't implement the `Comparable<E>` interface when calling the `contains` method.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to delete all its content - even if it's been closed as a duplicate (which I don't agree with in this case, I think @LuiggiMendoza's answer is most likely the appropriate one) it should be left in situ so the answers that were written before the close still make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you're assuming all your data in your class **must** implement the `Comparable` interface, then you should add it in the class declaration, or else you could get a `ClassCastException` when using this method in a class that doesn't implement this interface.

```
public class SomeClass<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    public boolean contains(E obj) {
        Node<E> curr = head;
        while (curr != null) {
        if (obj.compareTo(curr.data) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //the rest of your implementation...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the signature of contains method as follows to avoid any type-casting while invoking `compareTo` method on obj:

```
public <E extends Comparable<E>> boolean contains(E obj)
{
    return true;
}
```

This will also mandate any E passed to contains method to already implement Comparable interface.

Comment: I don't think this will work, since he appears to be implementing the `List<E>` interface, so he can't change the method signature.

Comment: I couldn't figure out from the question that he is implementing List<E>?

Comment: @JakeKing OP doesn't says that his class is implementing `List` interface.

Comment: @Vikdor based in OP's actual code, the `<E extends Comparable<E>>` is clumsy, because the class has the `<E>` template.

Comment: Eh, I suppose not. Fair enough.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, If the class itself has this, then `<E extends Comparable<E>>` should be in the class definition, I believe.

Comment: @Vikdor that's in my answer :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, just got to see it ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that this is a flawed implementation of a `contains(...)` method. Objects should not have to be comparable, they must only be equatable. Simply use `equals(...)` instead:

```
public boolean contains(E obj) {
    Node<E> curr = head;

    while (curr != null) {
        if (curr.data.equals(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
        curr = curr.next();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution, it forces to the `<E>` class to implement the `public boolean equals(Object o)` method, maybe OP doesn't need this at all.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `Object` contains a default implementation for `equals(Object)`, which compares by reference (aka `==`) by default. This will use that implementation unless a subclass overrides it. This is a better solution since it doesn't require unnecessary use of the Comparable interface and it uses a built-in method for all objects.

Comment: Maybe OP classes don't implement the `equals` method, instead by  looking his/her code the `E` class should implement the `Comparable<E>`. We should guide OP to the better solution, not to add restrictions like this to the actual code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza A class that implements Comparable *should* implement `equals(...)`, though not perhaps the other way around. If a comparable object doesn't implement equals I consider it a design flaw and illogical.

Comment: *It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))*, from [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). It could be a flaw, or maybe not, but that's out of the scope of this question.