# Warning while using reflection and generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

How do I rewrite this:

```
<T> T callMethod(String methodName, Object[] parameters) throws ... {
    ...
    return (T) SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes).invoke(binding, parameters);
}
```

so it doesn't generate a warning

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        return (T) SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes).invoke(binding, parameters);
required: T
found:    Object
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>callMethod(String,Object[])
```

I mean the no-SupressWarnings solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter Lawrey [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14120586/697449):

> There is no way the compiler can determine at compile time that the
>   method you select at runtime will have the return type of `T`.

I'll go a step further and say that `callMethod` should not be a generic method at all. Since the caller decides what method is called by passing its name as a string, the method should just return `Object` - like `invoke` - and force the call site to cast.

Do not use `@SuppressWarnings` - there's no way to justify it here.

Comment: I feel the need to justify why I checkmarked your answer. It made me rethink what I've wrote, and remove the generic character of callMethod and, as you mentioned, using casts on the calling site instead. This way not only warnings are gone, but also my code is prettier and I've learn something useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I think you'll have to live with the `@SuppressWarnings(...)` approach since the [`invoke()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) returns an `Object`. Remember that generics are erased at runtime, and reflection happens at runtime...

Cheers,

Comment: You don't know that the generic parameter is correct. You really do not want to be doing this sort of cast.

Comment: I quite agree, but provided that the OP wants to return `T` there's really no other options than live with or suppressing the cast warning...

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup, There is. You just need to provide that information by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way the compiler can determine at compile time that the method you select at runtime will have the return type of T.  You can only suppress the warning at compile time.

Comment: Or you can pass the information that type you expect on runtime.

Answer (score 2):

To do that you must declare the result type in the method parameter.

```
public <T> T callMethod(Class<T> resultType, String methodName, Object[] parameters) {

Object result = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes).invoke(binding, parameters);

if(resultType.isInstance(result)) {
  return resultType.cast(result);
}

throw new ClassCastException("Invalid result type");

}
```

Why do you must ?

See Peter L. answer.

Comment: Yeap. That one is more appropriate.

Comment: I would remove the `isInstance` check. `Class.cast` is doing the work. (Actually, I'd also check that the return type of the method was statically correct before calling it. Or more probably, avoid using reflection at all.)

Answer (score 0):

you have not used `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation.

`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` can only be applied to the declaration of the object, this will work:

Comment: Do you mean `@SuppressWarnings` ? ;)