# How do I pass an ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> between Activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I am trying to pass an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` between Activities. How would I do this with Intents?

Comment: Since all of those implement `Serianlizable`, I think you can through `Intent.putExtra()`. ([Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayList are Serializable (as well as HashMaps and Strings), so try [`putExtra(String, Serializable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29).

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("key", list);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean putExtra("list", (Serializable) myList) ?

Comment: Yes, you need to cast it to a Serializable if you use `List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();` since a List is an interface and the actual class doesn't _necessarily_ implement Serializable.

Comment: Hmm I did the above and I'm having trouble getting the data in my other activity. I am doing this: Intent intent = getIntent();
  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = bundle.get("list");

Comment: Try: [`bundle.getSerializable("list")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getSerializable%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks it works but I get this: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Serializable to ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>. Should I worry about that?

Comment: Since you put the Serializable data in yourself, you can ignore it and safely suppress this warning.  Here is more detail on why it's happening: [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509076/1267661)

Answer (score 0):

Use `putExtra(String, Serializable)` to pass the value in an `Intent` and `getSerializableExtra(String)` method to retrieve the data.

**Passing an ArrayList> from Activity A to Activity B**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("sunil", "sahoo");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
arl.add(hm);
intent.putExtra("arraylist", arl);
startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
```

**Retrieve the data in Activity B**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
System.out.println("...serialized data.."+arl);
```