# How to typesafe cast a generic list in java?

Tags: java

Is there a way to do this without the need to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

```
if (o instanceof Map) {
    Map<Object, Object> newMap = (Map<Object, Object>) o;
    ...
}
```

Comment: In what other cases are you not expecting `o` to be a `Map`?

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings

Comment: I'm not receiving an unchecked warning using Eclipse...

Comment: In case of just <Object,Object> the usage of Map<?,?> does not give off a warning for me. Also please note that any generic argument information is not kept at runtime. You could for example do (o instanceof Map<?,?>) without issues, but doing (o instanceof Map<Object,Object>) will give you an error.

Comment: Something tells me that this is the kind of thing that can be done in a completely different way if you take a look at the big picture. Can you share a bit more of what you're trying to do as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to the map, the short answer is no. Well you can code it as in example given in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings) mentioned by @brso05, but I think this is just defying the purpose. Basically the compiler tells you it cannot make sure types in the map are compatible.

If you don't have to write to that map you can use `Map<?, ?>`, which means that you can only get items of type `Object` from it. Like for example:

```
Map untypedMap = new HashMap();
Map<?, ?> map = untypedMap;
Object someValue = map.get(aKey);
```

#### Reasoning

The reason for that is that Java collections are not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

Just for simplicity sake, let's talk about Lists (but it applies to Maps also).

The following is not valid in Java (and for a good reason):

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Object> objects = integers; // illegal
```

Collections in Java are mutable, which means you could do something like this:

```
objects.add(1.4f);
```

This would alter the original `integers` list, and will ad a float to it. The float is an object so it typechecks against `List<Object>`.

Now because of backwards compatibility this kinds of assignments are possible, if a list is untyped. For example:

```
List untyped = new ArrayList();
List<Integer> integers = untyped; // warning here
integers.add(1);
List<Float> floats = untyped; // warning here
floats.add(1.4f);
```

So the code compiles, but is faulty. Consider following example.

```
System.out.println(untyped.get(0)); // is okay
System.out.println(untyped.get(1)); // is okay

Float aFloat = floats.get(0);// compiles, but throws ClassCastException
System.out.println(aFloat);
Integer anInteger = integers.get(1);// compiles, but ClassCastException
System.out.println(anInteger);
```

Because of above, whenever you assign an untyped collection to a typed collection, a compiler issues a warning.