# Sending arraylist of objects using serializable

Tags: android, serialization, arraylist

I am storing my JSON data into a arraylist of objects, my object class is Venue and I am  passing that data into another activity using serializable from fragment but I am not receiving any values in the actvity. It is receiving the extra. bundle is not null.

My code is:

**Fragment:**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchVenueActivity.class);

 //pass values
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putSerializable("arrayListVenue",arrayListVenue);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity:**

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("arrayListVenue")) {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null)
        rowItems = (ArrayList<Venue>) bundle.getSerializable("arrayListVenue");
    else
        Log.e("null","null");
}
```

**Venue Class:**

```
public class Venue implements Serializable{

    String venue_id;
    String venue_name;
    String venue_address;
    String venue_city;

    public String getVenue_city() {
        return venue_city;
    }

    public void setVenue_city(String venue_city) {
        this.venue_city = venue_city;
    }

    public Venue(String venue_id, String venue_name, String venue_address, String venue_city, String venue_zip, String venue_phone, String venue_mobile) {
        this.venue_id = venue_id;
        this.venue_name = venue_name;
        this.venue_address = venue_address;
        this.venue_city = venue_city;

        this.venue_zip = venue_zip;
        this.venue_phone = venue_phone;
        this.venue_mobile = venue_mobile;
    }

    public String getVenue_id() {
        return venue_id;
    }

    public void setVenue_id(String venue_id) {
        this.venue_id = venue_id;
    }

    public String getVenue_name() {
        return venue_name;
    }

    public void setVenue_name(String venue_name) {
        this.venue_name = venue_name;
    } 
}
```

Comment: what happens ? `rowItems` is null ?

Comment: and are you sure that `arrayListVenue` is not null?

Comment: @Blackbelt: yes m sure

Comment: try to add a generated serialVersionUID

Comment: is the following statement is true in your code? `getIntent().hasExtra("arrayListVenue")`

Comment: try `intent.putExtra("arrayListVenue",arrayListVenue); ` and `getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayListVenue");` instead of your code.

Comment: @Neha private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L; put something like this on the Venue class. then show me the logcat warning/eror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("arrayListVenue",arrayListVenue);` for putting arraylist to intent and use `intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("arrayListVenue")` for get arraylist back from intent in your SearchVenueActivity activity 
**Edit**
[Tutorial for using parcelable](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html)

Comment: using parceable leads to a lot of modification in my venue activity

Comment: @jaiSoni you need tell about `parcelable` and how to implement that and how to use that, it's good to show OP to what is the benefit of using parcelable

Comment: @Neha you don't have to make any change as Parceable class extends Serializable

Comment: i have accepted your answer because i learned parceble through it..my code worked without this too :) Thank you

Answer (score 18):

**try this way may this help you**

**First you want to make**

**Class Venue  implements Serializable**

```
public class Venue implements Serializable {
  /**
  * 
  */

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 }
```

**In your FirstActivity do this way**

```
  ArrayList<Venue> VenueArrayList = new ArrayList<Venue>();

  Intent intent = new Intent(this,secondActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("VenueArrayList", VenueArrayList);
```

**In your SecondActivity do this way**

```
  ArrayList<Venue> VenueArrayList;
  VenueArrayList = (ArrayList<Venue>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
        "VenueArrayList");
```

Comment: This causes a warning to be thrown out by Android Studio.

Comment: Why casting `Serializable` to `List<Object>` causes: `Unchecked Cast` warning?

Comment: @Mahdi Moqadasi can you please refer this link : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings

Comment: if you are passing List< Venue > typecast it while passing. ie. intent.putExtra("VenueArrayList", (ArrayList<Venue>)VenueArrayList);

Answer (score 4):

Learn from my mistakes.

I've tried to send Arrays and big objects using *Serializable*then my app got really slow. Did some tests and found out that when it took a lot of cpu and time to parse it. Therefore (altough its not what you would call best practice) i've created a *CacheManager* that store object for short time periods and used it to pass larger object between fragments activities.

If you want to make a more readical change to your design (later on in my project i did exactly that) then seperate the data from your fragment/activity completely and load it by *LoaderManagers* and pass only specific id's or stuff like that (stored stuff in the db in my case so it was easier).

Answer (score 0):

Use Array List instead of Bundle Elements.
In your Main Activity, try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newactivity.class);
intent.putParceableListArrayExtra("your_array_list_name", arrayList);
```

In the next activity where you want to retreive it, just use:

```
getIntent().getExtra("your_array_list_name", new ArrayList<> arrayList2);
```