# how to handle Unchecked cast warning in java code

Tags: java

I am unable to handle Unchecked cast warning in my java code :

```
Set<String> set1=new HashSet<String>();
            Object obj="apple";
            set1=(Set<String>)obj;  // warning Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Set<String>
```

in 3rd line I am getting an warning. How can I remove this. Please suggest. I don't want to use suppress warning code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings

Comment: your code is guaranteed to throw a ClassCastException, as you can't cast a `String` to `Set<String>`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to add elements to a Set of Strings your code should be:

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
String obj = "apple";
set1.add(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of the warning without either suppressing it, or completely changing the meaning of the code *as written*.

And even if you do suppress the warning, you will *still* get an exception at runtime because you are casting a `String` to a `Set`.  That can never work.

It is difficult suggest a correction because you don't say what you are actually trying to do here.  (I can think of three possibilities ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
String obj ="apple";
set1.add(obj);
```

also see [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)