# How to address Type safety warning Unchecked cast from Collection to List<File> Java 6 without suppress annotation

Tags: java, list, collections, warnings

I have the following code:

```
public void someMethod(String directory,final String extension) {

    List<File> fileList = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(directory), new String[] {extension} , true); 
    File[] files = new File[fileList.size()];
    // ...

    for(File f : files) {
       // looping...
    }
}
```

I get the yellow sqiggley line in my code with the warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Collection to List

How can I fix this?

**Edit 1:**

Please no suppression annotations, I'd like to understand what is happening. I've tried doing this:

```
if(fileList instanceof List<?>) {
    // data processing here...
}
```

this didn't make the warning go away...this is really bothering me...

**Edit 2:**

I've decided to do this:

```
List<?> fileList = (List<?>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(directory), new String[] {extension} , true);

File[] files = new File[fileList.size()];

int i=0;
if(fileList instanceof List<?>) {
    for (Object obj : fileList) {
        try {
            File file = (File)obj;
            files[i] = new File(file.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should work with `List`, won't with `List<anything>`. Your currently having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings - can you make `FileUtils` return a `Collection<File>` instead of raw `Collection`?

Comment: What is FileUtils?

Comment: @zapl no, as it is an external library I am using

Comment: @shmosel it's an apache io library

Comment: You can look into updating the library. They changed that. ps: your instanceof check is not needed. It's a list at that point or would have crashed when assinging to `fileList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, `Collection` is a superinterface of `List`, so unless you are sure that your implementation of `listFiles()` will *always* return a `List`, you shouldn't downcast (so as to avoid a [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)). In most cases, if you need a list instead of a collection, it's wiser to simply create a new list from the returned collection, e.g.,

```
Collection<File> myCollection = FileUtils.listFiles(...);
List<File> myList = new ArrayList<File>(myCollection);
```

Alternatively, if all you want to do is convert the collection into an array, there's no need to create any list at all. All you have to do is:

```
Collection<File> myCollection = FileUtils.listFiles(...);
File[] myArray = myCollection.toArray(new File[myCollection.size()]);
```

If the compiler continues to give you warnings, then your only remaining problem lies with the `listFiles()` method itself; it's returning the [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `Collection` instead of the [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) `Collection<File>`. To remove the associated warning, either update to the [latest version of Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), or simply insert the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation appropriately, e.g.,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Collection<File> myCollection = FileUtils.listFiles(...);
```

Comment: So you are saying there is no preferential way to go from Collection<File> to List<File>? This doesn't seem right...

Comment: @MoonieAsemani If you are asking if you can *change* the type of an object from `Collection` to `List`, then no, you cannot. This is because, while *all lists are collections, not all collections are lists*. I.e., `Collection` is a superinterface of `List`, not the other way around. Casting a collection that is not a list to a list will result in a `ClassCastException`, as I described above.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a `List<File>`? Why not do: `Collection<File> files=FileUtils.listFiles(...)`? This won't give you a warning and you can still iterate over your `Collection` of files

Comment: `Collection<File>` would result in the same warning, and I like working with List

Comment: It seems the warning is rooted with the type casting

Comment: you are right. you can try this `Collection mycol = FileUtils.listFiles(...);
        if (!mycol.isEmpty()) {
            List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>(mycol.size());
            for (Object colItem : mycol) {
                if (colItem instanceof File) {
                    fileList.add((File) colItem);
                }
            }
        }
`