# Detect if Object is a List<String>

Tags: java, list

I want to be sure if the object I get is a List of Strings.
Here's my code:

```
Object obj = plugin.getConfig().get("groups");
if(obj instanceof List<?>){ // Is the Object a List ?
    List<?> list = (List<?>) obj;
    if(list.get(0) instanceof String){ // Does the List contain Strings ?
        List<String> groupList = (List<String>) list;
    }
}
```

But Eclipse says that the last cast on line 5 isn't safe:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#3-of ?> to List<String>

How can I fix that? I've also tried

```
List<String> groupList = (List<String>) obj;
```

...but I still get the same error (basically).

Comment: That's just a warning. Does your code not work?

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? Eclipse says it's unsafe because it *is* unsafe in the general case: imagine a `List<Object>` where the first item is a `String`.

Answer (score -1):

Bottom line is, you cannot prevent this warning if you want to do a cast of the whole list, you can only supress it with an annotation.

See this answer for an explanation (it's about Map instead of List, but the same principles apply): [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)

If you want to have code without unsafe casts and without annotations you can take the approach in the accepted answer from the above question: do not cast the list itself, but iterate through the `List<?>` and cast each individual `Object` to `String`.