# Unchecked cast warning in code

Tags: java, android

My code:

```
 private List<Day> readDays(File file) {
        List<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            days.addAll((List<Day>) in.readObject());
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Logger.logError(LOG_TAG, e);
        }
        return days;
    }
```

Unchecked cast problem in this code

```
 days.addAll((List<Day>) in.readObject());
```

And this is a problem, in some cases the app crashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)

Comment: I cant comment on your question so... On a related post someone found that as to be the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509230/5554959 Maybe it could help.

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is cast object; you can define a convertor to convert your object to your class and handle exceptions.

if your stream return json string, You can use ObejctMapper and convert json string to your class as follow method by using jackson library:

```
    //create ObjectMapper instance
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //convert json string to object
    Day day = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Day.class); 

   // use day class now
```

so converting object, depend on your file data format.