# List of Maps : Camel Sql Type reference

Tags: java, generics, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel to execute an [sql](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) command. My results are returned back as a list of maps. Hence, I have to use something like this to type reference my results:

```
final List<Map<String, String>> results = exchange.getIn()
            .getHeader(Constants.SQL_RESULTS, List.class);
```

Note: I am retrieving the results by reading them from the header.

As a result, I am getting this warning in eclipse:

```
Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<Map<String,String>>
```

This warning makes sense to me, but I am unaware of any native java way or camel way to return a class type reference to a List of Map objects.

Question: How can I fetch an object from a camel header by specifying this class type:

```
List<Map<String, String>>
```

( If possible to solve with java 7 or 8, without altering the camel route, I am also interested in knowing how )

Comment: Well, that's more of a Java Generics problem than an `Apache Camel` problem. Possibility of finding a way around it is unlikely to be worth the time + effort and it may cause other complicated kludge as you can see in closely related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings). Currently we throw @SuppressWarnings at it and I am equally curious what solutions could be possible!