# ActionEvent.getSource: how to cast properly the source Object

Tags: java, swing, casting, actionlistener, jcombobox

I fear I may be making a newbie error here. I have the `ActionListener` below, but I get the warning `Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'javax.swing.JComboBox<java.lang.String>'` inside the `if` statement. How can I solve it? I want to invoke a method from the `JComboBox` API.

---

*I am not interested in suppressing the warning.*

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Object source = actionEvent.getSource();
        JComboBox<String> comboBox;
        if (source instanceof JComboBox) {
            comboBox = (JComboBox<String>) source;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't. See this for more details: [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the warning without suppressing, you will have to compromise with the generics and change the code to:

```
JComboBox<?> comboBox;
if (source instanceof JComboBox) {
    comboBox = (JComboBox<?>) source;
}
```

And if you are going to use any method from `JComboBox` which uses the generic `<E>`, you can use casting there. For example:

```
String s = (String) comboBox.getItemAt(0);
```

**Explanation:**

The warning was given because there is no way for the compiler to know whether your `JComboBox` is a `JComboBox<String>` or a `JComboBox<Integer>`.

Casting is a runtime thing and generics in Java are just placeholders to ensure type safety and to make the code more readable. Using Type Erasure, the compiler updates/modifies all statements involving generics with casting statements while generating the byte code (more info [here](https://javapapers.com/core-java/type-erasure/)).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: thanks @Trojan by the way using jdk 16 or above we can use pattern match the if statment could be written as `if (source instanceof JComboBox<?> comboBox)` this will create JcomboBOx<?> called comboBox if the source is instance of it so no need to create the variable or do the cast