# Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#2-of ?> to Class<? extends Throwable>

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am creating a function where I want to register different type of Exception in external library. They already have a method defined which accept Class as parameter.

I want to read different exception from configuration and register it, however I am getting typecast warning. I can ignore/suppress it, but is there any way to not suppress it?

The exact warning is `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#2-of ?> to Class<? extends Throwable>`

Here is the sample code which throws warning

```java
Class<?> exceptionClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Exception"); //Getting this value from Config. Let us assume that config is good and I get only valid classname which extends Throwable
registerExceptionInExternalLibrary((Class<? extends Throwable>)exceptionClass); // Getting the warning here
```

I think I cannot do casting here, since there is not object. But if I do not use casting, then I get this warning

`The method registerExceptionInExternalLibrary(Class<? extends Throwable>) in the type XXXXX is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ?>)`

Here is that code sample

```java
Class<?> exceptionClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Exception"); //Getting this value from Config. Let us assume that config is good and I get only valid classname which extends Throwable
registerExceptionInExternalLibrary(exceptionClass); // Getting the warning here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Class.asSubClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass-java.lang.Class-) for this.

```
Class<?> exceptionClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Exception");
registerExceptionInExternalLibrary(exceptionClass.asSubclass(Throwable.class));
```

The complete code of the method is as follows and shows you're just offloading the cast (and warning suppression) to a JDK method, so there's nothing too magical about it. But it's very handy in `map()` chains, and works nicely here too. Also it does verify that you're making a correct cast with `isAssignableFrom`, which is the extra functionality that you'd forget to write if you just did the cast yourself and suppressed the warning.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <U> Class<? extends U> asSubclass(Class<U> clazz) {
    if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(this))
        return (Class<? extends U>) this;
    else
        throw new ClassCastException(this.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings) about unchecked casts.

In short, the compiler can't be sure if the `exceptionClass` is a variable of type `Class<? extends Throwable>`, so you will get a warning anyway.

You can use @SuppressWarnings annotation with limited scope:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<? extends Throwable> exceptionClass = (Class<? extends Throwable>)Class.forName("java.lang.Exception");
```

The annotation here will not affect the entire method.

Comment: I don't want to use @SuppressWarnings.

I had tried this and get warning `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Class<? extends Throwable>`