# How to fix incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>

Tags: java, object, java-8, casting

I have a hashmap defined like this that I cant change

```
private Map<String, Object> attributes;
```

The object is a list of Strings (sometimes size == 1, other times > 1).

I have an instance of the *attributes* map later on in the execution. I am wanna get the Object as List.

This:

```
List<String> outputs = attributes.get("keys");
```

throws this error.

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `List<String> outputs = (List<String>) attributes.get("keys");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit cast:

```
List<String> outputs = (List<String>) attributes.get("keys");
```

Note that this is an [unchecked cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509076/10819573) and may throw `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: You should explain that this is an unchecked cast, and what that means for type safety.