# How to address "Unchecked cast from Object to CriteriaComboBox<TEST.Criteria>" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unchecked-cast

I'd like to know how to avoid this unchecked cast warning in eclipse even though it might not be necessary since I know what types i'm putting into the object. My CriteriaComboBox extends a RenderedComboBox which extends a JComboBox. My class is of type TEST.Criteria.

Can someone advise if this is just a bug in eclipse? Should I just add a suppress warning? Or am I not doing this correctly?

[image]

Here is the code snippet:

```
                        // identify the source dropdown component
                        Object source = evt.getSource();
                        CriteriaComboBox<TEST.Criteria> cBox = null;
                        if (source instanceof CriteriaComboBox) {
                            cBox = (CriteriaComboBox<TEST.Criteria>) source;
                        }
```

This also give me the same warning:

```
                        if (source instanceof CriteriaComboBox) {
                            cBox = (CriteriaComboBox<TEST.Criteria>) source;
                        }
```

My version of eclipse is 2021-12 (4.22.0) running on ubuntu.

Comment: "since I know what types I'm putting", yes, you do. Your compiler, however, doesn't. evt.getSource() returns an Object, not (necessarily) one of type CriteriaComboBox. There is quite a bit of related code missing. But, indeed, just because the compiler checked that your object is of type CriteriaComboBox, it doesn't mean it checked the types added to it.

Comment: @Stultuske could you give me a hint at the related code I am missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings

Comment: @simgineer we have no idea what "evt" is, we can only guess, yet you want us to know everything it does/return on a method call?

Comment: @Stultuske evt is an ActionEvent from an overridden actionPerformed method. Sorry guess that was specified in the attached image.

Comment: You will just have to suppress this warning, there is no way to convince Java it is safe.