# serialVersionUID for serizlizable class

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean: The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288937/what-does-it-mean-the-serializable-class-does-not-declare-a-static-final-serial)

> The serializable class
>   VaadintestprojectApplication does not
>   declare a static final
>   serialVersionUID field of type long

1. What does this statement mean? I get
   an error for this.
2. What does serizlizable class do and
   why do we need to declare a static
   final for it.

Comment: 1. It not an error, its a warning. 2. If you don't know what the Serializable *interface* does, why are you using it?

Comment: I am learning stuffs.. not using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [`Serializable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) javadoc, which explains this far better than any StackOverflow contributor.