# What does the "declare a static final serialVersionUID" warning mean and how to fix?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean: The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288937/what-does-it-mean-the-serializable-class-does-not-declare-a-static-final-serial)

Java compiler warning: `The serializable class [*****] does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long.`

Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is explained fairly well [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45):

> *The serialVersionUID is a universal version identifier for a Serializable class. Deserialization uses this number to ensure that a loaded class corresponds exactly to a serialized object. If no match is found, then an InvalidClassException is thrown.*

You fix the error by adding

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;  // unique id
```

to the class.

**Further reading:**

- [java.io.Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)
- [Why should I bother about serialVersionUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid) (stackoverflow)

---

**A side note:** If you're using Eclipse and if you (and no one else) ever plan to serialize your classes, you can also suppress the error by going to

Window → Preferences → Java → Compiler → Errors/Warnings

and select "Ignore" on "Serializable Class without serialVersionUID".

Comment: How do you generate 7526472295622776147L?

Comment: You just pick a random (unique) long value. In eclipse you could do *Source Cleanup...->Custome Profile->Missing Code->Add serial version ID*

Comment: Thanks aioobe, that last bit was what I needed to know.

Comment: aioobe, no explicitly assinging a serialVersionUID in my serializables can cause the application to randomly generated one after each compilation?

Answer (score 6):

just add

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;//or some long
```

[Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) describe it pretty well

> The serialization runtime associates
>   with each serializable class a version
>   number, called a serialVersionUID,
>   which is used during deserialization
>   to verify that the sender and receiver
>   of a serialized object have loaded
>   classes for that object that are
>   compatible with respect to
>   serialization. If the receiver has
>   loaded a class for the object that has
>   a different serialVersionUID than that
>   of the corresponding sender's class,
>   then deserialization will result in an
>   InvalidClassException. A serializable
>   class can declare its own
>   serialVersionUID explicitly by
>   declaring a field named
>   "serialVersionUID" that must be
>   static, final, and of type long:
>
> ```
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
> ```
>
> If a
>   serializable class does not explicitly
>   declare a serialVersionUID, then the
>   serialization runtime will calculate a
>   default serialVersionUID value for
>   that class based on various aspects of
>   the class, as described in the
>   Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification. However, it is strongly
>   recommended that all serializable
>   classes explicitly declare
>   serialVersionUID values, since the
>   default serialVersionUID computation
>   is highly sensitive to class details
>   that may vary depending on compiler
>   implementations, and can thus result
>   in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions
>   during deserialization. Therefore, to
>   guarantee a consistent
>   serialVersionUID value across
>   different java compiler
>   implementations, a serializable class
>   must declare an explicit
>   serialVersionUID value. It is also
>   strongly advised that explicit
>   serialVersionUID declarations use the
>   private modifier where possible, since
>   such declarations apply only to the
>   immediately declaring
>   class--serialVersionUID fields are not
>   useful as inherited members.

**Also See**

- [why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid)

Comment: Why downvote ? can you please explain ..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps because it is a verbose copy from the source of [Jon Skeets answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid/285809#285809).

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 1):

Declare it like that:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4673040337179571462L;
```

Its required by serializable interface.

Comment: How do you generate -4673040337179571462L

Answer (score 0):

Are you extending a Swing object?

I often use the @suppressWarnings annotation to rid myself of this warning.

I guess the question of surpressing the warning or supplying a unique ID depends on the scale of your application and your intended use of Object serialisation.