# SerialVersionUID field for static final variables

Tags: eclipse, gwt

For converting a integer into an enum (out of a json file), I declared some HashMaps like this:

```
final static HashMap<Integer, Types> getType = new HashMap<Integer, Types>() {
    {
        put(1, Types.TYPE1);
        put(2, Types.TYPE2);
        ....
    }
};
```

Now eclipse gives me the following warning:

```
The serializable class  does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long
```

I already found a pretty good explanation for the error message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288937/what-does-it-mean-the-serializable-class-does-not-declare-a-static-final-serial). However I don't know how this is with GWT. Does GWT use the SerialVersionUID anywhere, or is it actually deleted by the closur compiler? As far as I see it, it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serialVersionUID` is only used for Java serialization (using the JVM `Serializable` contract), which is (quite obviously) not supported in GWT.

That means you can safely ignore the warning; and you can also safely add a `serialVersionUID` to appease Eclipse, as it'll be pruned by the compiler.
(I believe you could also configure Eclipse so it doesn't generate the warning)

Also, you shouldn't initialze your `HashMap` that way (that is, create an anonymous subclass of `HashMap` that initializes itself in its initializer). You'd better use a static initializer:

```java
final static Map<Integer, Types> getType;
static {
   getType = new HashMap<Integer, types>();
   getType.put(1, Types.TYPE1);
   getType.put(2, Types.TYPE2);
   ...
   // you could even use Collections.unmodifiableMap here
}
```

or use [Guava's ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):
    final static Map getType = ImmutableMap.builder()
       .put(1, Types.TYPE1)
       .put(1, Types.TYPE2)
       ...
       .build();

Better yet, if your integer values map with the enum constants' declaration order, you can simply use Enum#values() instead of map:

```java
Types typeFromInt(int i) {
   return Types.values()[i];
}
```

Comment: thanks, ImmutableMap was right what I wanted! Types.values()[i]; 
 doesn't work for me, since the numers are not from one to 10 but 1,2, 5, 6...... :/