# Getting Yellow error/warnings with code

Tags: java, serialization, error-handling, compiler-errors

Before we start i need a solution that involves adding no extra code to the shown class, it must be as is. Not sure if that is possible but if not id like to find that out too so i can get down to the real problem.

Hey so iv been given a half complete code for my assignment and was told to create the missing classes using the 2 classes they gave me and fix all errors, while never changing anything on the given classes. So far iv made all the classes with auto generated methods and stuff, i managed to fix all red errors but the code will still give me errors when compiling :/ So i thought maybe its got to do with this yellow error and after a couple days i cant figure out how to fix it :( So i was hoping you guys would know what this yellow error mean.

Error 1: GameManager

```
public class GameManager extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
```

It says that game manager "The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field." but i cant add any code to this class :/

Screenshot of compiling error: http://prntscr.com/je580m

Full Code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameManager extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

private int canvasWidth;
private int canvasHeight;
private int borderLeft;
private int borderTop;
private BufferedImage canvas;
private Stage stage;
private Enemy[] enemies;
private Player player;
private Goal goal;
private Graphics gameGraphics;
private Graphics canvasGraphics;
private int numEnemies;
private boolean continueGame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // During development, you can adjust the values provided in the brackets below
    // as needed. However, your code must work with different/valid combinations
    // of values.
    GameManager managerObj = new GameManager(1920, 1280, 30);
}

public GameManager(int preferredWidth, int preferredHeight, int maxEnemies) {
    this.borderLeft = getInsets().left;
    this.borderTop = getInsets().top;
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    if (screenSize.width < preferredWidth)
        this.canvasWidth = screenSize.width - getInsets().left - getInsets().right;
    else
        this.canvasWidth = preferredWidth - getInsets().left - getInsets().right;
    if (screenSize.height < preferredHeight)
        this.canvasHeight = screenSize.height - getInsets().top - getInsets().bottom;
    else
        this.canvasHeight = preferredHeight - getInsets().top - getInsets().bottom;
    setSize(this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    Random rng = new Random(2);
    this.canvas = new BufferedImage(this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    // Create a Stage object to hold the background images
    this.stage = new Stage();
    // Create a Goal object with its initial x and y coordinates
    this.goal = new Goal(this.canvasWidth / 2, Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % this.canvasHeight);
    // Create a Player object with its initial x and y coordinates
    this.player = new Player(this.canvasWidth - (Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % (this.canvasWidth / 2)),
            (Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % this.canvasHeight));
    // Create the Enemy objects, each with a reference to this (GameManager) object
    // and their initial x and y coordinates.
    this.numEnemies = maxEnemies;
    this.enemies = new Enemy[this.numEnemies];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
        this.enemies[i] = new Enemy(this, Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % (this.canvasWidth / 4),
                Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % this.canvasHeight);
    }
    this.gameGraphics = getGraphics();
    this.canvasGraphics = this.canvas.getGraphics();
    this.continueGame = true;
    while (this.continueGame) {
        updateCanvas();
    }
    this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
    updateCanvas();
}

public void updateCanvas() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    // If the player is alive, this should move the player in the direction of the
    // key that has been pressed
    // Note: See keyPressed and keyReleased methods in the GameManager class.
    this.player.performAction();
    // If the enemy is alive, the enemy must move towards the goal. The goal object
    // is obtained
    // via the GameManager object that is given at the time of creating an Enemy
    // object.
    // Note: The amount that the enemy moves by must be much smaller than that of
    // the player above
    // or else the game becomes too hard to play.
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
        this.enemies[i].performAction();
    }
    if ((Math.abs(this.goal.getX() - this.player.getX()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))
            && (Math.abs(this.goal.getY() - this.player.getY()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
            // Sets the image of the enemy to the "dead" image and sets its status to
            // indicate dead
            this.enemies[i].die();
        }
        // Sets the image of the enemy to the "dead" image and sets its status to
        // indicate dead
        this.goal.die();
        // Sets the background of the stage to the finished game background.
        this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
        this.continueGame = false;
    }
    // If an enemy is close to the goal, the player and goal die
    int j = 0;
    while (j < this.numEnemies) {
        if ((Math.abs(this.goal.getX() - this.enemies[j].getX()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))
                && (Math.abs(this.goal.getY() - this.enemies[j].getY()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth()
                        / 2))) {
            this.player.die();
            this.goal.die();
            this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
            j = this.numEnemies;
            this.continueGame = false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    try {
        // Draw stage
        this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(stage.getCurrentImage(), 0, 0, null);
        // Draw player
        this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(player.getCurrentImage(),
                this.player.getX() - (this.player.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
                this.player.getY() - (this.player.getCurrentImage().getHeight() / 2), null);
        // Draw enemies
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
            this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage(),
                    this.enemies[i].getX() - (this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
                    this.enemies[i].getY() - (this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage().getHeight() / 2), null);
        }
        // Draw goal
        this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(this.goal.getCurrentImage(),
                this.goal.getX() - (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
                this.goal.getY() - (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getHeight() / 2), null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    // Draw everything.
    this.gameGraphics.drawImage(this.canvas, this.borderLeft, this.borderTop, this);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    this.gameGraphics.drawString("FPS: " + String.format("%2d", (int) (1000000000.0 / (end - start))),
            this.borderLeft + 50, this.borderTop + 50);
}

public Goal getGoal() {
    return this.goal;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    // Below, the setKey method is used to tell the Player object which key is
    // currently pressed.
    // The Player object must keep track of the pressed key and use it for
    // determining the direction
    // to move.
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        this.player.setKey('L', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        this.player.setKey('R', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        this.player.setKey('U', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        this.player.setKey('D', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
        this.continueGame = false;
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    // Below, the setKey method is used to tell the Player object which key is
    // currently released.
    // The Player object must keep track of the pressed key and use it for
    // determining the direction
    // to move.
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        this.player.setKey('L', false);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        this.player.setKey('R', false);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        this.player.setKey('U', false);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        this.player.setKey('D', false);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
}
```

}

My Goal Class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Goal {

    private BufferedImage imageRunning;
    private BufferedImage imageOver;
    private BufferedImage imageCurrent;

    public Goal() {
        try {
            this.imageRunning = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\HUS\\Desktop\\image-file\\stage-normal.png"));
            this.imageOver = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\HUS\\Desktop\\image-file\\stage-gameover.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.imageCurrent = this.imageRunning;
    }

    public BufferedImage getCurrentImage() {
        return this.imageCurrent;
    }

    public void setGameOverBackground() {
        this.imageCurrent = this.imageOver;
    }



public Goal(int i, int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Dimension getCurrentImage1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public int getY() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public int getX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public void die() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean: The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288937/what-does-it-mean-the-serializable-class-does-not-declare-a-static-final-serial)

Comment: @Turamarth that does get rid of it but it also adds in code, im not even sure if there is a way to fix it without adding code but if there isnt id like to know so i can bring it up with my professor

Answer (score -1):

Check the line 93:

```
this.goal.getCurrentImage()
```

You did not initialize `currentImage` hence you get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: what do u mean by initialize? how can i get that done