# How to get rid of this generics warning?

Tags: java, generics, easymock

I am trying to mock a generic interface, and whenever I mock it, I gets this warning:

> The expression of type GenericInterface needs unchecked conversion to conform to GenericInterface<String>

My interface is

```
interface GenericInterface<T>{
    public T get();
}
```

and my test is

```
@Test
public void testGenericMethod(){
    GenericInterface<String> mockedInterface = EasyMock.createMock(GenericInterface.class);
}
```

I get warning at the first line in test case.

How do I remove this generic warning?

Answer (score 12):

The correct steps to get rid of the warning is:

- First and foremost, *prove* that the unchecked cast is safe, and *document why*
- Only then perform the unchecked cast, and annotate `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the variable declaration (not on the whole method)

So something like this:

```
// this cast is correct because...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
GenericInterface<String> mockedInterface =
    (GenericInterface<String>) EasyMock.createMock(GenericInterface.class);
```

---

#### Guidelines

The following is excerpt from *Effective Java 2nd Edition: Item 24: Eliminate unchecked warnings*:

> - Eliminate every unchecked warning that you can.
> - If you can't eliminate a warning, and you can prove that the code that provoked the warning is typesafe, then (and only then) suppress the warning with  `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` annotation.
> - Always use the `SuppressWarning` annotation on the smallest scope possible.
> - Every time you use an `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` annotation, add a comment saying why it's safe to do so.

#### Related questions

- [What is `SuppressWarnings (“unchecked”)` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java)
- [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)
- [Type safety: Unchecked cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast)

---

#### Refactoring the cast

It is also possible in most cases to perform the unchecked cast inside a generified `createMock`. It looks something like this:

```
static <E> Set<E> newSet(Class<? extends Set> klazz) {
    try {
        // cast is safe because newly instantiated set is empty
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Set<E> set = (Set<E>) klazz.newInstance();
        return set;
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);          
    }
}
```

Then elsewhere you can simply do:

```
// compiles fine with no unchecked cast warnings!
Set<String> names = newSet(HashSet.class);
Set<Integer> nums = newSet(TreeSet.class);
```

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/)
- [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

Comment: Asking for feedback: is it true that the cast in `newSet` is considered "safe"? I don't think it actually is, because one can create `SpecializedStringSet implements Set<String>`, and `Set<Integer> nums = newSet(SpecializedStringSet.class);` could throw `ClassCastException` at run-time on `add`, right? I'll edit this into the answer based on comments.

Comment: you are correct, it is not safe, that is why you have to suppress warnings.

Comment: @Yishai: it's unchecked, which is why you have to suppress the warning. I'm wondering if it's also unsafe. Just because it's unchecked doesn't mean it's unsafe. If it's unsafe, then suppressing the warning is foolish. If it's provably safe, then suppress away and you're fine.

Comment: you demonstrated that it is unsafe in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that EasyMock.createMock() is going to return an object of type `GenericInterface` and not `GenericInterface<String>`. You could use the `@SupressWarnings` annotation to ignore the warning, or you could try and explicit cast to `GenericInterface<String>` (I think this just gives a different warning though.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, apparently I fail at escaping angle brackets or something...

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t147848-generics-in-1-5-nonsense-warnings.html
- http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=635608

seem to discuss the same warning...

i guess @SuppressWarnings might be the key to happiness in that case

Comment: ... along with a comment explaning the justification for using `@SuppressWarnings` - http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA117&ots=yXJnRho1Q1&dq=effective%20java%20suppresswarnings&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

If you are really stuck up on avoiding the compiler warning, you can declare an interface in your test just for the purpose of avoiding it.

```
 interface MockGenericInterface extends GenericInterface<String> {}
```

Then you can do:

```
 GenericInterface<String> mockedInterface = EasyMock.createMock(MockGenericInterface.class);
```