# Static factory method with generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `EnumConverter<T extends Enum<?>>` that converts strings to the correct enum constant for the enum `T` (I can't use `Enum.valueOf`). I construct instances of this class in a factory method like this:

```
public static <T extends Enum<?>> EnumConverter<T> getInstance(Class<T> enumClass) {
    return new EnumConverter<T>(enumClass.getEnumConstants());
}
```

This works, but now I want to cache `EnumConverter` instances to make sure there is only one per enum, i.e. with a `Map`, and my problem is how to declare this `Map`. The closest I have come is this:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, EnumConverter<? extends Enum<?>>>
```

But I get an error if I try to return a value from this `Map` from my factory method:

> `Type mismatch: cannot convert from EnumConverter<capture#1-of ? extends Enum<?>> to EnumConverter<T>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to store different sub types in the map, the compiler can't know which actual subtype you are receiving. I think you have to add a cast:

```
public static <T extends Enum<?>> EnumConverter<T> getInstance(Class<T> enumClass) {
    return (EnumConverter<T>) cache.get(enumClass);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! But I still get a warning: `Type safety: Unchecked cast from EnumConverter<capture#3-of ? extends Enum<?>> to EnumConverter<T>`. But this is probably not possible to address due to type erasure?

Comment: The answer is indeed `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast