# how do i get rid of a "Unchecked cast" warning?

Tags: java, android

```
Map<String,?> one = (Map<String,?>) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

`Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,?>`

with the above line of code i get that unchecked cast warning. what is the best way for me to have the same results but alleviate that warning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type safety: Unchecked cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast)

Comment: What is the type of `parent`?

Answer (score 2):

Add this annotation to the method:

`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Object to Map.`

Be sure to comment it -- in a large method it may not be obvious.