# Warning in instantiating a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I have a snippet code for instantiation of a generic type as following:

```
public class GenericMessageMapper<I ,X>
{
   public X xFromI(I imf)
   {
      // do thing by imf argument
      Class<X> clazz = (Class<X>)((ParameterizedType)
                                   this.getClass()
                                       .getGenericSuperclass())
                                       .getActualTypeArguments()[1];
      X x = clazz.newInstance(); 
   }
}
```

Above code worked fine but `MyEclipse` show a warning on the code(a yellow under line  on preparing `clazz` variable line) by this message :`Type safety: Unchecked cast from Type to Class<X>`

I temporary add following annotation in above of `xFromI` method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

What is reason of this warning and what is solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ftom2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812303/ftom2) is right - in usual situation you should perform instance check (`instanceof`) before cast in case of this warning. But in your case this is impossible because generics in Java was implemented by erasure. `Class<X>` is not reified type so it is impossible to use it for instance check and only way to turn off the warning is to use `@SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")`. 
To learn more about generics you can use [this](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Java_Generics_And_Collections.html?id=zaoK0Z2STlkC&redir_esc=y) book.

Answer (score 2):

A warning is just that. A warning. Sometimes warnings are irrelevant, sometimes they're not. They're used to call your attention to something that the compiler thinks could be a problem, but may not be.

In the case of casts, it's always going to give a warning in this case. If you are absolutely certain that a particular cast will be safe, then you should consider adding an annotation like this just before the line:

```
@SuppressWarnings (value="unchecked")
```

refer [Type safety: Unchecked cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast)

Answer (score 1):

It only means that the type of the class is only known at runtime, so a situation could arise where you think you are supposed to get a class of type X but actually it is of other type (it doesn't know it in compile time since X can be of any type).

Basically you can ignore this warning.