# Cannot convert generic to expanded nested type

Tags: java, generics

Recently I was refactoring a generic method when I got into generic casting issues I cannot explain. Finally I realized I could do without the T type altogether (just inline it myself), but I'm still curious as to why the convert fail. 
I created this minimal example to illustrate the issue.

**Can someone explain me why the convert fails and the workaround works?**

```
public <K, T extends List<K>> void castLists(List<T> list, K kForBinging) {
    Map<Integer, List<T>> map = mapSizeToList(list);
    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Integer,List<T>> to Map<Integer,List<List<K>>>
    // Map<Integer, List<List<K>>> expandedMap = map;

    // Added after accepting answer, legal assignment:
    Map<Integer, ? extends List<? extends List<K>>> expandedMap = map;

    // Originally proposed 'work around'
    Map<Integer, ?> lessSpecific = map;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<Integer, List<List<K>>> canCast = (Map<Integer, List<List<K>>>)lessSpecific;
    // ...
}

public <A> Map<Integer, List<A>> mapSizeToList(List<A> list) {
    Map<Integer, List<A>> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    // ...
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need **[Covariance with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)** before you can do such things. **This doesnt seem to be supported by Java**.

i.e in Java, if `T` is a subtype of `List<K>`, it **does NOT imply** that `List<T>` is a subtype of `List<List<K>>` or that `Map<Integer,List<T>>` is a subtype of `Map<Integer, List<List<K>>>`. This is why the **assignment errors out**.

**Covariance** would allow you to do this because with it, **if template parameters have a subclass-superclass relationship**, the **defined classes** will also have the **exact same relationship**. This would make this assignment possible. **Scala** (among other (functional programming?) languages) supports **covariance** and its complement **contravariance**.

Comment: However, List<List<K>> expandedLists = (List<List<K>>)list; is assignable. But I see that is regardless of the binding of T.

Comment: @Stim, im rusty in Java, but in C++ that would be an unsafe cast, infact I understand that [this would result in an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast) had you not suspended it on purpose. If you were to check the type with `isinstanceof` I expect it will return false?

Comment: It is not possible to verify the parametrized type using instanceof in java. But you are right, the assignment causes compiler warnings.

Comment: Thanks @Karthik for pointing out the issue. With your help I was able to construct a legal assignment without a cast, see the question again.