# Overloading of methods in Java

Tags: java, oop, overloading

In the following code snippet, there are three versions of a method named `show()`.

```
package overloading;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class Main
{
    private void show(Object object)
    {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    private void show(List<Object> list)  //Unused method
    {
        System.out.println("List");
    }

    private void show(Object[] objects)
    {
        System.out.println("Objects");
    }

    private void addToList()
    {
        List<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("String1");
        list.add("String2");
        list.add("String3");
        show(list); // Invokes the first version

        String []s={"111", "222", "333"};
        show(s);   // Invokes the last version
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Main().addToList();
    }
}
```

In this simplest of Java code, this method call `show(s);` (the last line in the `addToList()` method) invokes the **last version** of the overloaded methods. It supplies an array of strings - `String[]` and it is accepted by the receiving parameter of type `Object[]`.

This function call `show(list);` however attempts to invoke the **first version** of the overloaded methods. It passes a list of type strings - `List<String>` which should be accepted by the middle version whose receiving parameter is of type `List<Object>` The middle version of the methods is completely unused. It is a compile-time error, if the first version is removed.

Why does this call `show(list);` **not** invoke this version - `private void show(List<Object> list){}` - the middle one?

Comment: +1. Interesting. Apparently, the compiler takes the generic type annotation into consideration and eliminates the overloaded method it would otherwise have chosen. I would have expected a compile error because the generic types don't match instead. If you remove the type annotation from `list` (make it `List list`), then the middle method does get chosen (with warnings and runtime error of course).

Comment: The middle version is chosen when the generic type parameter with  `list` is removed.

Comment: With autoboxing, varargs and generics, method dispatch has becoming really complex since Java 5. This makes for a great (or at least tricky) exam question.

Comment: A good explanation of this is Brian Goetz's article [_Generic gotchas_](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, `List<Object>` is NOT `List<String>`.

To "fix" your code, use the following code

```
private void show(List<? extends Object> list)
{
    System.out.println("List");
}
```

Unlike arrays (which are covariant in Java), different instantiations of a generic type are not compatible to each other, not even explicitly.

With the declaration `Generic<Supertype> superGeneric; Generic<Subtype> subGeneric;`
the compiler would report a conversion error for both castings `(Generic<Subtype>)superGeneric` and `(Generic<Supertype>)subGeneric`.

This incompatibility may be softened by the **wildcard** if `?` is used as actual type parameter: `Generic<?>` is the abstract supertype for all instantiations of the generic type.

Also [see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_%28Java%29)

Answer (score 4):

`List<Object>` is not a superclass of `List<String>` in java. What you are assuming is that Java has covariance on generics, which it does NOT.

What this means is that if `A` is a superclass of `B`, `List<A>` is NOT a superclass of `List<B>`

A similar problem is faced in [Cannot convert generic to expanded nested type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969435/cannot-convert-generic-to-expanded-nested-type), You can see if any of the work arounds there works for you.

Perhaps changing

```
private void show(List<Object> list)
```

to

```
private void show(List<? extends Object> list)
```

Would work as you would expect?

Comment: @Thilo why would there be an error? There might have been an error if  the `show(Object object)` version did not exist.

Comment: I would not have expected that `List<Object>` gets discarded as the best choice by the compiler. I would have expected it to still dispatch there (but then complain about the mismatch). That seems to be more predictable behaviour to me. I would not have expected generics to affect which methods gets chosen. But seems I was wrong. With autoboxing, varargs and generics, method dispatch has becoming *really* complex since Java 5. This makes for a great (or at least tricky) exam question.

Comment: @Thilo That is the reason for the failure, It would have been picked if `list` was a `List<Object>`, But since it is an UNRELATED type to `List<Object>`, it fails. If java supported covariance like Scala does, it would have worked.

Comment: Yes, and since Java does not, I would have preferred a compile error to silently dispatching to the "wrong" method.

Comment: @Thilo The problem is there is no inherent compile error here. You are assuming its an error since you expect that List<Object> is a superclass of List<String> . The best you can expect in such cases is a compiler warning (in its most paranoid setting) or a feature in the [Lint type applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) to catch this

Comment: @Thilo - But it's not the wrong method. It's just not what you (er, OP) intended, but how is the compiler supposed to know that? It found a matching method and was happy.

Comment: In other words, I had thought that adding type annotations to your program may make it stop compiling because of additional checks, but does not affect *how* it gets compiled.

Comment: @TedHopp: "It found a matching method and was happy." Yes, the problem is that those matching rules have to become too complex. It should not match another method because of the type annotation IMO. All this should do is reject the method otherwise matched and then *error out* (not choose another one). Principle of Least Surprise definitely violated here.

Comment: @KarthikT: No.  What I would have expected (and wanted) is that it does not consider generics at all when selecting the method. That would match `List<Object>` (with Object "erased"). But that match would then be discarded and compilation aborted because of the generic type mismatch. Since, as you have pointed out, there is no generic covariance and no generic overloading in Java anyway, why drag generics into method selection at all?

Comment: @Thilo - But what if one wanted `show(Object object)` specifically to handle all arguments that were not `List<Object>` or `Object[]`? That seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to do and you would change the language to make it impossible!

Comment: @TedHopp: You can cast to Object to achieve that. Let me ask you then, what if one wanted to also have a `show(List<String>)` or a `show(List<?>)` or a `show(List)` in addition? Java does not let you do that. There is no generic covariance and no generic overloading in Java anyway, so why drag generics into method selection at all?

Comment: @Thilo - I agree; Java generics are very weak in that regard. Good point about requiring an explicit cast. It would certainly remove the mystery from how OP's code works (or doesn't, depending on your pov).

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is because the parameters are different, `List <Object>` Differs from `List <String>`
Therefore when you call the overloaded method, it would default to the first one accepting just an Object.

Here is a short example:

```
public class Test
{
  public static void overload (Object o)
  {
    System.out.println ("Object");

  }

   public static void overload (List <Object> o)
  {
    System.out.println ("List Object");
  }

   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
     overload (new ArrayList <Object>()); //"List Object"
     overload (new ArrayList <String>()); //"Object"

   }
}
```

Parameterize the list with generics and everything should work.