# Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<MyObject>

Tags: android, listview, casting, filter, custom-object

I have a ListView listing a custom object (let's say `MyObject`).

I want to filter it dynamically through an `EditText` so I had to implement a `getFilter()` with a publishResults method:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    MyObjectAdapter.this.setItems((List<MyObject>) results.values);
    MyObjectAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

At this point, Eclipse complains: `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<MyObject>`

I am sure this cast will always be true, but Eclipse only suggests to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` but I'm totally against `SuppressWarnings` because it's only hiding the problem, not a solution...

I tried adding:

```
if(results.values instanceof List<MyObject>)
```

But Eclipse complains again, and this solves nothing...

`Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type List<MyObject>. Use the form List<?>`

I know the casting will always be correct, but which is the proper way to make the code to be sure `results.values` is actually a `List<MyObject>` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to find a solution.

Just as @Medo42 said:

> Another option is to check for and cast to List as the instanceof
>   error suggests. Then you can iterate over the elements in the list and
>   check if they are actually all instances of MyObject, and copy them to
>   a new List.

Even though I did not went through the process of creating a whole new object in order to make this particular case to work "warning-less" this was the right direction to go.

So I took @lokoko 's idea and use it in a new `setItems()` method, with an `Object` parameter instead of a `List<MyObject>` in order to make sure

The result code is the following:

```
public void setItems(List<MyObject> var){
    this.list = var;
}

public void setItems(Object var){
    List<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    if (var instanceof List){
        for(int i = 0; i < ((List<?>)var).size(); i++){
            Object item = ((List<?>) var).get(i);
            if(item instanceof MyObject){
                result.add((MyObject) item);
            }
        }
    }
    setItems(result);
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 26):

If all you have to work from is an `Object`, then you can't check at runtime that you actually have a `List<MyObject>`, because the generic type `MyObject` is only used for compile-time type checking, it is *not* available at runtime. This is why you get an error when you try to add the `instanceof` check.

If you are sure that your `Object` really is always a `List<MyObject>` then I'd say the `@SuppressWarnings` is OK, if you document why you are sure it is not a problem.

If you absolutely want to avoid a warning though, you could create your own `List` implementation (say, `MyObjectList`) that is not itself generic but implements `List<MyObject>`. Then you can do an `instanceof` check against `MyObjectList` at runtime.

Another option is to check for and cast to `List<?>` as the `instanceof` error suggests. Then you can iterate over the elements in the list and check if they are actually all instances of MyObject, and copy them to a new `List<MyObject>`.

Answer (score 17):

Try something like this :

```
List<?> result = (List<?>) results.values;
for (Object object : result) {
    if (object instanceof MyObject) {
        tempList.add((MyObject) object); // <-- add to temp
    }
}

filteredItems = tempList; // <-- set filtered
```

Comment: Your solution helped me to figure out how to solve my problem, thx!

Answer (score 3):

You can perform the checking before passing it to `setItems()`.

```
final Object myListObj = reuslts.values;
if(myListObj instanceof List<?>) {
    if(((List<?>)myListObj).get(0) instanceof MyObject)
        // You can safely suppress the warning here because you made sure it is a List containing MyObject
        MyObjectAdapter.this.setItems((List<? extends MyObject>) myListObj);

}
```

However, you need to change your `setItems()` method accordingly:

```
public void setItems(List<? extends MyObject> list) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: This check only ensures that the *first* object in the list is a `MyObject`, so the only thing you have shown is that the list *can* contain such elements - not that it actually is a `List<MyObject>` or even a `List<? extends MyObject>`. Rather, you have shown that it is a `List<? super MyObject>`.

Comment: You are correct. However, a `List<String>` can never contains an element of `Integer` right? If `MyObject` has no subclass this works well. Even if the objects inside `extends MyObject`, they all contains necessary interface or functions that `MyObjectAdapter` required, because method signature decladed `MyObject`, not other subclasses.

Comment: Technically, a `List<String>` *can* contain an `Integer` because the generic type of the list is not enforced at runtime. But even if you had that guarantee and even if `MyObject` has no subclasses your suggestion isn't valid. Imagine a `List<Object>` that contains one `MyObject` and one String. Your check would cast that to `List<? extends MyObject>` because the first element happens to be a `MyObject`, but trying to get the second element throught that casted list would cause a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: For me I did:
val imageList: List<Any> = snapshot.value as ArrayList<Any>