# How can I solve this Java warning?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle, findbugs

I hate working with parametrics, they are open doors for bad code practices and mistakes. However people do use them often so I try to live with it.

I am struggling to solve this warning condition, however I have no idea how to properly fix this.

[image]

```
/**
 * Enables incoming connections from any remote address and disables authentication (cross-origin access should be blocked
 * when entering in production).
 * 
 * @param serverResource
 * @return
 */
private static Series<Header> configureRestForm(ServerResource serverResource) {
    final Object responseHeaders = serverResource.getResponse().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
    final Series<Header> headers;
    if (responseHeaders instanceof Series<?>) {
        headers = (Series<Header>) responseHeaders;
    } else {
        headers = new Series<Header>(Header.class);
        serverResource.getResponse().getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", headers);
    }
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60");
    return headers;
}
```

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: one possibility: add SupressWarnings as annotation to the method as you can see in the warning dialog itselfs.

Comment: each cast is dirty. another possibility is the adapter pattern.

Comment: You have to cast.. there is no other possibility as serverResource.getResponse().getAttributes() returns an object. Applying SupressWarnings will make eclipse recognize that you have accepted defeat and allowed the warning to remain there..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type safety: Unchecked cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation or try 
change Eclipse preferences: `Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings->Generic types` and check the `Ignore unavoidable generic type problems` check-box

Comment: In the code you can use only SuppressWarnings annotation. There is no another solution for parameterised generics (Map or List etc)