# How to get rid of "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,String>"

Tags: java, dictionary, spring-security

I am using below code to extract `deviceId` from Spring Authentication class.

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public static Optional<String> getId() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (!auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return Optional.absent();
    }
    // I see a warning as "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,String>"
    Map<String, String> details = (Map<String, String>) auth.getDetails();
    return Optional.of(details.get("deviceId"));
}
```

How do I get over of this Type safety warning message? I want to avoid adding `Suprress Warnings` tag.

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from `Object` to `Map<String,String>`

Comment: I would be surprised if this were possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Since [`Authentication`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) simply defines return value of [`getDetails()`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getDetails--) as an `Object`, you have to cast, and although the type `Map` will be checked at runtime, there is still no guarantee that it maps `String` to `String` (because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)).

This means that you *may* get a `ClassCastException` at some later point, when the `Map` is used. That is what the warning is trying to tell you, and you accept responsibility for that by adding `@SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What is the right way to use it then?

Comment: Add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` where you want. If you add it to the statement, it won't accidentally hide another case of the warning that may occur later on during development, which could be the case if added to method or class.

Answer (score 1):

By checking the type before performing a cast.

```
if(auth.getDetails() instanceof Map){
   //here your cast
}
```

... your question may be a duplicate to:
[Type safety: Unchecked cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast)