# Java Map/JSONObject put method using String key (Map<?,?> Casting problems)

Tags: java, dictionary, casting

So, the problem is the following. I have a method which I want to make it work for Maps and for JSONObject, so it can be called in both cases.

After some operations, I need to put into that Map/JSONObject an Object. I am trying to do this:

```
private void putDefaultValue(Object obj) {
    //... some code...
    String key = "key";
    Object objectToUpdate = ...; //whatever
    //... some code...
    if (obj instanceof Map) ((Map<?,?>)obj).put(key, objectToUpdate);
    else if (obj instanceof JSONObject) ((JSONObject)obj).put(key, objectToUpdate);
}
```

The JSONObject does not give any problem, but the Map casting forces the error:

> The method put(capture#6-of ?, capture#7-of ?) in the type
>   Map is not applicable for the arguments
>   (String, Object)

I can change the `Map<?,?>` casting for `Map<String,Object>` but then I get a warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Map

I would not like to add any suppress warnings, and be able to do this in a propper way. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Try doing this: `if(obj instanceof Map) (Map<String, Object>)obj.put(key, objectToUpdate);`

Comment: Don't worry about warning about using `Map<String,Object>` and have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/262416/517134