# Adding and retrieving objects with nested fields (Firestore)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm quite new to cloud Firestore but I'm trying to learn it to my best.

Can someone please explain how could I add an object (with nested fields) in a document and then retrieve/get it back?

I know how to add data (such as String) through `Hashmap` and `add()` method and get it back using `get()` method but I have no idea about Objects.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT:** I studied the android developer docs and found solution to add objects with nested fields in it. but now I'm struggling with how to retrieve them. I tried the following code:

```
DocumentReference docRef = 
db.collection("Users").document("myDocument");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>({

@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document != null) {
            Object object = task.getResult().getData().get("myObject");
            String str = object.toString();
            tv.setText(str);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
    }
   }
});
```

it's showing the objects's value not the nested fields' value within the object. How can i get the field values of the object? By the way, I checked the following post [Accessing data stored as object in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885472/accessing-data-stored-as-object-in-firestore-database) and tried it's answer but my app gets crashed with the following log error:

```
" java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object 
 reference
```

Any opinion/help would be much appreciated!
                                                       "

Answer (score 1):

`document.getData()` returns "almost" JSON data. This can be interpreted by using Gson and JsonElement. Example: if objectName refers to the name of object and Classname is the name of the class of desired object,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(document.getData());
Classname objectName = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Classname.class);
```

The code can be shortened like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Classname objectName = gson.fromJson(gson.toJsonTree(document.getData()), Classname.class);
```

Incase you wanted a HashMap, you can cast it like this

```
HashMap<String, FieldValueClass> map = (HashMap<String, FieldValueClass>)(document.getData()).
```

But this works only when all fields can be cast to `FieldValueClass`.