# How do I solve unchecked cast warnings in Java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, type-safety

I have a `jsp` scriplet where I wrote this code

```
Object obj=session.getAttribute("ListOfCountry");

HashMap<Integer, String> hm = (HashMap<Integer, String>) obj;
```

But it says `"Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to (HashMap <Integer, String>)" error`. Any idea to resolve it?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast

Comment: [Easy: Don't write scriptlets.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: @spbhasnalkar were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

**NOTE:** First, you need to check if obj is a HashMap or not.

> Replace this:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hm = (HashMap<Integer, String>) obj;
```

> With this:

```
if(obj instanceof HashMap) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> hm = (HashMap<Integer, String>) obj;
}
```

Alternative Solution is that you can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to stop that warning.