# Java with Eclipse: Type Safety: The Expression of type map needs unchecked conversion to confirm to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, apache-camel, type-safety

How to remove type safety markers for following "Map" in Java usingEclipse?

```
Map<String, String> errorStatus = exchange.getIn().getHeader("totalCount", Map.class);
```

It prints following message.

```
The Expression of type map needs unchecked conversion to confirm to Map<String,String>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**:

getIn() and getHeader are inbuilt Camel Method. In a route, i have setHeader("headerkey",mapOfErrors) and when i need this error key further i am just fetching it from Camel Message using those functions.
Following are available parameters of getHeader():
[image]

Comment: It looks like one of those "you can't" situations because the inherent flaws in Java's type system. But I can't say for sure with so little information.

Comment: @Amongalen Since when can you do `Map<String,String>.class`?

Comment: @Amongalen Try it.

Comment: If not then shall i write it like Map in place of Map<String, String>

Comment: @fatherazrael No, you should still use `Map<String, String>`. If this is really one of those "you can't" situations, you can put a `@SuppressWarnings`. But as I said, **I can't tell unless you tell me more information.** For example, what is `getHeader`? What is `getIn`? *What are you doing?*

Comment: @Sweeper getIn() and getHeader are inbuilt Camel Method. In a route, i have setHeader("headerkey",mapOfErrors) and when i need this error key further i am just fetching it from Camel Message using those functions. I have updated all methods available in description

Comment: I think your question has been answered at following links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/262416/2689980  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/509115/2689980

Answer (score 0):

As you know there is no `Map<String,String>.class`, so as far as I know for your case you have two options:
first create a wrapper class to extend the HashMap and you can use the Wapper.class, ***which I don't recommend***

`WrapperClass errorStatus = exchange.getIn().getHeader("totalCount", Wrapper.class);`

The second approach just ignore this warning and use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`