# Generic type, cast to method,field

Tags: java, generics, lambda, reflection

i have this class

```
class GameLoaderClass<V> {

V classValue = null;

Class<?> aClass;

ClassType classType;

public GameLoaderClass(ClassType classType, Class<?> aClass) {
    this.classType = classType;
    this.aClass = aClass;
}

public V getClassType(String name) {
    if (this.classType == ClassType.FIELD) {
        return this.classValue = aClass.getDeclaredField(name);
    } else
        return this.classValue = aClass.getMethod(name);

}
```

But i get this following error..

Required type: C
Provided: Method

any way to fix it?, thanks

Comment: Define class like `class GameLoaderClass<V extends java.lang.reflect.Member>` and use type casts `return this.classValue = (V)aClass.getMethod(name);`

Comment: @onkarruikar Yes casting it works, but is not safe, i want know if there is a way without cast

Comment: @Mekdbd Do you want the `Method` object to be assigned to `classValue` or do you want the `classValue` to be assigned the value returned by the method named `name` ?

Comment: @GauthamM Yes i want the method object be assigned to classValue, but the object can be a field too, i only want to return the value as generic without casting.

Comment: You have to assure the compiler that you are going to assign a assignable value to the variable. Hence the cast is needed. Use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on method `getClassType`.

Comment: This discussion has useful info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast

Answer (score 0):

I would be better to use return type `Object` instead of using generics.

```java
public Member getClassType(String name) {
    if (this.classType == ClassType.FIELD) {
        return aClass.getDeclaredField(name);
    } 
    return aClass.getMethod(name);
}
```

And in the place where you call the method you could do

```java
Member obj = loader.getClassType("someName");
if(o instance of Field) {
    Field f = (Field) obj;
    // do the rest
} else /* Assuming Field or Method are the possible types of returned objects */ {
    Method m = (Method) obj;
    // do the rest
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on @Onkar's comment, it would be better to return an object of type `Member` instead of `Object` as both `Method` and `Field` implement `Member`.

Comment: `java.lang.reflect.Member` would be a better choice than Object

Comment: @onkarruikar yes that was a good info. I have updated

Comment: @onkarruikar Yes is a good solution, but i wanted to use generics so i can use that way

Method method = new GameLoaderClass<Method>().getClassType(ClassType.Method);

Comment: @Mekdbd You could still do that right? `Method method = (Method) new GameLoaderClass(ClassType.Method, SomeClass.class).getClassType("someName");`

Comment: @GauthamM i want use generics without casting

Comment: @Mekdbd You need to use casting at one point either use casting inside the `GameLoader` class or in the place where you invoke the `getClassType` method. Otherwise I think it won't be possible.